# Dynamically bind mysqli_stmt parameters and then bind result

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to dynamically bind mysql_stmt parameters and get the result in an associative array. I've found this post here on Stack Overflow where Amber posted an answer with the following code:

Original post:
[How to make a proper mysqli extension class with prepared statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384191/how-to-make-a-proper-mysqli-extension-class-with-prepared-statements/1384214#1384214)

"Assuming you're actually wanting to write your own version (as opposed to utilizing one of the existing libraries other answers have suggested - and those are good options, too)...

Here are a couple of functions which you may find it useful to examine. The first allows you to bind the results of a query to an associative array, and the second allows you to pass in two arrays, one an ordered array of keys and the other an associative array of data for those keys and have that data bound into a prepared statement:"

```
function stmt_bind_assoc (&$stmt, &$out) {
    $data = mysqli_stmt_result_metadata($stmt);
    $fields = array();
    $out = array();

$fields[0] = $stmt;
$count = 1;

while($field = mysqli_fetch_field($data)) {
    $fields[$count] = &$out[$field->name];
    $count++;
}
call_user_func_array(mysqli_stmt_bind_result, $fields);

}

function stmt_bind_params($stmt, $fields, $data) {
    // Dynamically build up the arguments for bind_param
    $paramstr = '';
    $params = array();
    foreach($fields as $key)
    {
        if(is_float($data[$key]))
            $paramstr .= 'd';
        elseif(is_int($data[$key]))
            $paramstr .= 'i';
        else
            $paramstr .= 's';
        $params[] = $data[$key];
    }
    array_unshift($params, $stmt, $paramstr);
    // and then call bind_param with the proper arguments
    call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', $params);
}
```

I tried studying the code to understand what it does and I've made the second function work properly but I don't know what I should do to be able to utilize the first function. How do I use it to retrieve an array similar to mysqli_result:: fetch_assoc()?

I want to be able to utilize the result in such a way like you used to do with:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row['foo']." ".$row['bar'];
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, here is a way to do it:

**Edited, to fix bug when fetching multiple rows**

```
$sql = "SELECT `first_name`,`last_name` FROM `users` WHERE `country` =? AND `state`=?";
$params = array('Australia','Victoria');

/*
    In my real app the below code is wrapped up in a class 
    But this is just for example's sake.
    You could easily throw it in a function or class
*/

// This will loop through params, and generate types. e.g. 'ss'
$types = '';                        
foreach($params as $param) {        
    if(is_int($param)) {
        $types .= 'i';              //integer
    } elseif (is_float($param)) {
        $types .= 'd';              //double
    } elseif (is_string($param)) {
        $types .= 's';              //string
    } else {
        $types .= 'b';              //blob and unknown
    }
}
array_unshift($params, $types);

// Start stmt
$query = $this->connection->stmt_init(); // $this->connection is the mysqli connection instance
if($query->prepare($sql)) {

    // Bind Params
    call_user_func_array(array($query,'bind_param'),$params);

    $query->execute(); 

    // Get metadata for field names
    $meta = $query->result_metadata();

    // initialise some empty arrays
    $fields = $results = array();

    // This is the tricky bit dynamically creating an array of variables to use
    // to bind the results
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
        $var = $field->name; 
        $$var = null; 
        $fields[$var] = &$$var; 
    }


    $fieldCount = count($fieldNames);

// Bind Results                                     
call_user_func_array(array($query,'bind_result'),$fields);

$i=0;
while ($query->fetch()){
    for($l=0;$l<$fieldCount;$l++) $results[$i][$fieldNames[$l]] = $fields[$fieldNames[$l]];
    $i++;
}

    $query->close();

    // And now we have a beautiful
    // array of results, just like
    //fetch_assoc
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: how does this works if the sql statement is $sql = "SELECT `first_name`,`last_name` FROM `users`"?

Comment: @lilsizzo Yes, I don't think that works. I came across this problem too and solved it. I don't have time to edit the above answer with my new code right now, but email me at: eman[AT]onlythebible[DOT]com and I can email you my class if you like.

Comment: this part of the code $results[] = $fields; will always assign value of last row into results. what if there is more than one row of result?

Comment: @lilsizzo - I don't quite get what you mean; That line `$results[] = $fields;` loads all of the results into an array `$results`. Just do `print_r($results)` to see all of the results. You'll need to do a `foreach` to loop through them.

Comment: Work only if one row is selected! If more than one row is selected, $results contains for every row one array but that array is always filled with the last entry from the result set!

Comment: Cant seem to get any of the results from a row... Just thr columns

Answer (score 8):

The Answer from Emmanuel works fine, if only one row is selected! If the query select multiple rows, the $results-Array holds for every row a result, but the result is always filled with the last entry. With a little change in the fetch()-while it work well.

$sqlStmt is an string, filled with the mysql-query

$params is an array, filled with the variables that should passed

$results is an empty array, that holds the result

```
    if (!is_string($sqlStmt) || empty($sqlStmt)) {
        return false;
    }

    // initialise some empty arrays
    $fields = array();
    $results = array();

    if ($stmt = $this->prepare($sqlStmt)) {
        // bind params if they are set
        if (!empty($params)) {
            $types = '';
            foreach($params as $param) {
                // set param type
                if (is_string($param)) {
                    $types .= 's';  // strings
                } else if (is_int($param)) {
                    $types .= 'i';  // integer
                } else if (is_float($param)) {
                    $types .= 'd';  // double
                } else {
                    $types .= 'b';  // default: blob and unknown types
                }
            }

            $bind_names[] = $types;
            for ($i=0; $i<count($params);$i++) {
                $bind_name = 'bind' . $i;       
                $$bind_name = $params[$i];      
                $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name;   
            }

            call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),$bind_names);
        }

        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        // Get metadata for field names
        $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

        // This is the tricky bit dynamically creating an array of variables to use
        // to bind the results
        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
            $var = $field->name; 
            $$var = null; 
            $fields[$var] = &$$var;
        }

        // Bind Results
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_result'),$fields);

        // Fetch Results
        $i = 0;
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $results[$i] = array();
            foreach($fields as $k => $v)
                $results[$i][$k] = $v;
            $i++;
        }

        // close statement
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

Comment: Just a note: this essentially replicates a sort of `MYSQLI_ASSOC` result set fetched as you'll get back something to the effect of `$result[0]['field_name'] = $field_value;` - not an issue really, just something to be aware of if you prefer to return your records with numeric indexes (for some reason), you'll need to tweak the code slightly.

Comment: I am not getting any results... I can only get the fields/columns, no row values... Any ideas?

Comment: This works but I only get the last column value. For example if I had... "select name, age, id from user"... it would run and for each user if I called $user['name'] it would return the id. same with $user['age'], it only stores the last value of id in all of the name, age, and id keys.

Answer (score 1):

Just to compare excellent answers from @Emmanuel and @matzino with the code you can get if choose PDO over mysqli:

```
$sql = "SELECT `first_name`,`last_name` FROM `users` WHERE `country` =? AND `state`=?";
$params = array('Australia','Victoria');

$stm = $query->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($params); 
$results = $stm->fetchAll(); // or fetch() or fetchColumn() depends on expected type
```

whoops, that's all?

Answer (score 0):

After using the answer above I have figured out that there was some cleanup needed for myself, particularly the 'fieldNames[]' portion. The code below is in procedural style. I hope it will come of use to someone.

I cut the code from a class I made that can dynamically query data. There are a few things I removed to make it easier to read. In the class I have I allow the user to define definitions tables and foreign keys so that data entry on the front-end is restricted as well as filter and sort options for said related data. These are all parameters I removed as well as the automated query builder.

```
$query = "SELECT `first_name`,`last_name` FROM `users` WHERE `country` =? AND `state`=?";
$params = array('Australia','Victoria');

////////////// GENERATE PARAMETER TYPES IF ANY //////////////
// This will loop through parameters, and generate types. ex: 'ss'
$types = '';
$params_size = sizeof($params);
if($params_size > 0)
{
    foreach($params as $param)
    {
        if(is_int($param))
        {
            $types .= 'i';              //integer
        }else if(is_float($param))
        {
            $types .= 'd';              //double
        }else if(is_string($param))
        {
            $types .= 's';              //string
        }else
        {
            $types .= 'b';              //blob and unknown
        }
    }
    array_unshift($params, $types);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// This is the tricky part to dynamically create an array of
// variables to use to bind the results

//below from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php
/*
name        The name of the column
orgname     Original column name if an alias was specified
table       The name of the table this field belongs to (if not calculated)
orgtable    Original table name if an alias was specified
def         Reserved for default value, currently always ""
db          Database (since PHP 5.3.6)
catalog     The catalog name, always "def" (since PHP 5.3.6)
max_length  The maximum width of the field for the result set.
length      The width of the field, as specified in the table definition.
charsetnr   The character set number for the field.
flags       An integer representing the bit-flags for the field.
type        The data type used for this field
decimals    The number of decimals used (for integer fields)
*/

/// FIELD TYPE REFERENCE ///
/*
numerics
-------------
BIT: 16
TINYINT: 1
BOOL: 1
SMALLINT: 2
MEDIUMINT: 9
INTEGER: 3
BIGINT: 8
SERIAL: 8
FLOAT: 4
DOUBLE: 5
DECIMAL: 246
NUMERIC: 246
FIXED: 246

dates
------------
DATE: 10
DATETIME: 12
TIMESTAMP: 7
TIME: 11
YEAR: 13

strings & binary
------------
CHAR: 254
VARCHAR: 253
ENUM: 254
SET: 254
BINARY: 254
VARBINARY: 253
TINYBLOB: 252
BLOB: 252
MEDIUMBLOB: 252
TINYTEXT: 252
TEXT: 252
MEDIUMTEXT: 252
LONGTEXT: 252
*/

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_link, $query))
{
    // BIND PARAMETERS IF ANY //
    if($params_size > 0)
    {
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), makeValuesReferenced($params));
    }

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $meta = mysqli_stmt_result_metadata($stmt);


    $field_names = array();
    $field_length = array();
    $field_type = array();
    $output_data = array();

    /// THIS GET THE NAMES OF THE FIELDS AND ASSIGNS NEW VARIABLES USING THE FIELD NAME. THESE VARIABLES ARE THEN SET TO NULL ///
    $count = 0;
    while($field = mysqli_fetch_field($meta))
    {
        $field_names[$count] = $field->name;// field names
        $var = $field->name;
        $$var = null;
        $field_names_variables[$var] = &$$var;// fields variables using the field name
        $field_length[$var] = $field->length;// field length as defined in table
        $field_type[$var] = $field->type;// field data type as defined in table (numeric return)
        $count++;
    }
    setFieldLengthInfo($field_length);
    setFieldTypesInfo($field_type);

    $field_names_variables_size = sizeof($field_names_variables);
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $field_names_variables);

    $count = 0;
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
    {
        for($l = 0; $l < $field_names_variables_size; $l++)
        {
            $output_data[$count][$field_names[$l]] = $field_names_variables[$field_names[$l]];/// THIS SETS ALL OF THE FINAL DATA USING THE DYNAMICALLY CREATED VARIABLES ABOVE
        }
        $count++;
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);


    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($output_data);
    echo "</pre>";
}


function makeValuesReferenced($arr)
{
    $refs = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value)
        $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
    return $refs;
}
```