# Is possible to enable MySQL Native Driver (mysqlnd)?

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqlnd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result)

My web host has PHP 5.3.10 and I'm using `mysqli`, but some functions like `get_result()`  doesn't work because it needs `mysqlnd`.

I made some tests and appears that `mysqlnd` isn't used. Is possible to enable it or is needed to reinstall PHP (I can't do this because is a web hosting).

I don't want to change my code to work without it.

Comment: @Repox Is not duplicate, I think. I already saw that question, but it doesn't answer what I asked here. That question pointed me the problem.

Comment: The problem is the same and a solution has been given (which means you can't fake or simulate the get_result() method in resource object).

Comment: Why was this closed as a duplicate? It's not (although this is a progression from the previous one). The previous question was "Why can't I use `mysqli_stmt::get_result`?", and the answer was "You need to enable mysqlnd to use it." This question is "How do I enable mysqlnd?" There is zero overlap between the scope of the answers given to the previous question and the scope of this question; the mention of `get_result` in this question is only there because it was the answer to the previous question that led the poster to ask this one.

Comment: I had this same question. It was answered here but not in the "duplicate" question. Why is this considered a duplicate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52955565/6094503 solved my problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mysqldnd` is a library that provides MySQL-connectivity to `mysql_*`, `mysqli_*` and PDO functions/methods.

Those three extensions are compiled either with `mysqlnd`, or with `libmysql` ; and cannot be compiled using both at the same time : they use one library, or the other.

This means the only way to switch between `libmysql` and `mysqlnd` is to re-compile PHP *(or, at least, the mysqli extension, in your case)* ; or to install a version of it that is compiled against the library you want.

Basically, this can only be done by the administrator of your server -- so, in your case, you seem to be stuck with `libmysql` ; even if it lacks some interesting features.

Once again, using an hosting service with which you are not administrator has advantages *(less maintenance for you, you probably pay less)*, but you are not able to do whatever you want with "your" server.

Comment: Seems I can't add an answer, so it has to be a comment. If your webhosting has cpanel it may have a "select PHP version" option. It did in my hosting Cpanel and in the Php Selector you can choose the extensions. I unchecked the mysql, mysqli, pdo_mysql extensions and checked the  nd_mysql, nd_mysqli, nd_pdo_mysql, and myslqnd extensions. This enabled MySQLnd. I can find no documentation for this hence it may not be 100% correct of which extensions need to be checked but I'd like the info to be available here as I couldn't find any info on it anywhere else

Comment: @Nat You did a great job by leaving a very useful comment here. It worked like a charm for me! Thanks.