# How do I return this value in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having a problem with this code:

```
$loginrequest = $mysqli->prepare(
    "SELECT name, password, salt FROM users WHERE name = ? OR email = ?");
$loginrequest->bind_param("ss", $login, $login);
$loginrequest->execute();
$loginrequest->bind_result($name, $encrypted_password, $salt);

while ($loginrequest->fetch()) {

  $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);

  if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
    return $name;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

As you can see I want to check a user login, and if the password is correct I want to return the username, otherwise false.

But don't I have to close the `$mysqli` query doing this?

```
$loginrequest->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Because the value `$name` is only available in the while loop (if I understood this correctly). I mean I could declare a string before and change it to the `$name` value, but is it necessary to close her?

By the way I can't use `store_result` since the PHP Version is too old.

Comment: Why would you want to use a while loop for this, there can be only one user row?

Comment: If you call `$mysqli->close()` you will no longer have access to the connection; this is different from calling close on the statement (`$loginrequest->close()`)

Comment: And you need not close your mysqli; it will close automatically.

Comment: On another note, calling a hashed password "encrypted" is a misnomer. Also, if possible, use a dedicated password hashing function like bcrypt or PBKDF2. Here's why: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/6415/4665

Comment: @NullUserException But if I do `$loginrequest->close()`, wouldnt that stop the fetch() method and kick me out of the loop?

Comment: But why do you have the `while` loop in the first place?

Comment: Because I found it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result) aswell as [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) in the examples. Though I wondered about this I though this is necessary, isn't it?

Comment: Also the so called "hash" method is actually creating a salted base64 string which I think is secure enough

Comment: @jtheman Yes, there can be only one.

Comment: No it's not. Just write: `$loginrequest->fetch();` You only need to bind the parameters once. Also you probably want to check the return on that - if it's false there was an error, if it's NULL there was no user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Closing statement doesn't unbound fetched variables.
- You fetch one row and return, so the `while` can be removed.

This will compare password and close statement:

```
    $loginrequest->fetch();
    $loginrequest->close();
    $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
    if ($encrypted_password == $hash)
      return $name;
    return false;
```