# mysqli multiple where clause for two different variables

Tags: php, get, mysqli, fatal-error

I have users current latitude and longitude saved as the variables `$latitude`  and `$longitude`. I only want the data from the database to echo out if the latitude and longitude matches the users current latitude and longitude.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_username","password","db_dbname");
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE geoloc1 = ? and geoloc2 = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $latitude, $longitude);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>

            <div class="latlon">
                <a><?php echo $row['geoloc1'] ?></a>
            </div>
<?php
}  
?>
```

yet Im getting the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()` and I can't seem to solve why its coming up!

Comment: "Please note that this method requires the mysqlnd driver. Otherwise you will get this error: `Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()`" - [Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

Comment: Im using the same method to input i believe so, i do think I have it.

Comment: This question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result) might be able to help

Comment: Shouldn't it be $stmt->get_result($result); not $result =.   EDIT: this may actually be wrong so feel free to ignore me :)

Comment: @Dave You only need to pass in a statement when using it procedurally (ie. `mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt)`)

Comment: You can pass the variable in, in OO too if your wanting to bind the output to that variable but thats more for returning a single result so you'd then just to echo $result after the fetch.  This doesn't work though if you're returning multiple columns.  Its basically short hand. look on the php mysqli::prepare page for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just quit that unusable mysqli and use PDO, which has 2 advantages: in is neat and it works.

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_dbname;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$con = new PDO($dsn, "db_username","password", $opt);

$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE geoloc1 = ? and geoloc2 = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($latitude, $longitude));
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($data as $row) {
?>
      <div class="latlon">
         <a><?php echo $row['geoloc1'] ?></a>
      </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: There's very little difference between the 2 for most users tbh.  Mysqli is arguably simplier for a new user to get into PDO has some oddities which can be confusing at first.