# PHP Prepared Statement/Bind Param Code Crashing

Tags: php, mysqli, internal-server-error

Can someone explain why this gives me a 500 internal server error? I tried adding some sql injection protection and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Should I be doing this in an object oriented style instead of procedural?

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd)or die("Error connecting to database.");
mysqli_select_db($conn, $db) or die("Couldn't select the database."); 
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email=? AND password=?";
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query) or die("Failed to prepare statement.");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1){
    //Log in successful 
}
else {
    //Wrong Username or Password        
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username, $password);` Shouldn't this be `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $password);`

Comment: Your statement has two bound parameters, but the call to mysql_stmt_bind_param only has one in it - the second parameter should be `"ss"`, as you're passing in two strings.

Comment: Not related to an error 500, but you don't need to escape strings that you _bind_ to the query. In fact, some queries may break when you do.

Comment: @crush Ok, I fixed that, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson noted, that was just left over from my first go at it. thanks.

Comment: Try commenting out all the lines, then uncommenting each until you get the error.

Comment: Look in the error logs, and see what's there.

Comment: The line $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt); seems to be causing the error.

Comment: @Rice_Crisp - try adding `echo mysqli_error($conn)` before that line

Comment: I found that the problem is that mysqli_stmt_get_result is an undefined function. Why is that?

Comment: Apparently, mysqli_stmt_get_result is PHP 5.3.0 or later - what version are you running?

Comment: Yup, that's it. I believe I'm running 5.1.

Comment: You should add that as an answer, and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt_get_result` is available in PHP 5.3, but I am running 5.1. Also, the mysqlnd driver must be installed for this call to work.

For more information, see [Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result)