# prepared statements fetch_assoc php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm having problems with listing out comments with prepared statements. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
$fetchComments = $cnx -> prepare("SELECT comment FROM comments WHERE video_id=? LIMIT 1");
$fetchComments -> bind_param('s', $row['id']);
$fetchComments -> execute();
$fetchComments -> store_result();
$fetchComments -> bind_result($vid_comment);
if ($fetchComments -> num_rows > 0) {
    whike ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vid_comment)){
    echo $row['comment'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where `$row['id']` come from?

Comment: And the problem is...?

Comment: there is a syntax error `whike` should be `while`

Comment: @Fabio The $row['id'] comes from a previous while loop that is looping through the posts. Within that loop, I'm trying to print out the comments. The syntax error is not in the source code (just here). The error I get is for the row with the while loop: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Comment: @Fabio Tried to user '$row2' - didn't work...

Comment: while ($fetchComments ->fetch()) { echo $vid_comment

Comment: this is because you are using object oriented so you cannot use mysqli_fetch_assoc that is procedural style

Comment: Worked -Thanks! :) To instead of mysqli_fetch_assoc in OOP it is ->fetch() ?

Comment: yeah this is object oriented and it's the correct one. Shall i post the answer so you can accept it?

Comment: Sure - go ahead! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your script. You are using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` while you have to use `fetch()`. The error is here

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vid_comment)){
```

So you should use instead

```
while ($fetchComments ->fetch()) {
   echo $vid_comment 
}
```

You can check [**documentation here**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Answer (score 8):

[For some unknown (and really weird) reason] you cannot use fetch_assoc on mysqli_stmt object.
you need to get mysqli result resource first with mysqli_get_result().

Also *please* name your variables consistently. Mysqli statement has nothing to do with your comments and knows nothing of them, nor contain them. It's just a mysqli statement object.

```
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result(); // here you go
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $row['comment'];
}
```

Though you never can tell whether this function would be available with mysqli or not.

Comment: If someone is also getting problem with get_result() please refer to this:
1. in case of fatal error install mysqlnd: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result
2. In case of no result remove line: "$stmt->store_result()" (rest unchanged)