# Example of how to use bind_result vs get_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I would like to see an example of how to call using `bind_result` vs. `get_result` and what would be the purpose of using one over the other.

Also the pro and cons of using each.

What is the limitation of using either and is there a difference.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Although both methods work with `*` queries, when `bind_result()` is used, the columns are usually listed explicitly in the query, so one can consult the list when assigning returned values in `bind_result()`, because the order of variables must strictly match the structure of the returned row.

### Example 1 for `$query1` using `bind_result()`

```
$query1 = 'SELECT id, first_name, last_name, username FROM `table` WHERE id = ?';
$id = 5;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query1);
/*
    Binds variables to prepared statement

    i    corresponding variable has type integer
    d    corresponding variable has type double
    s    corresponding variable has type string
    b    corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
*/
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

/* Store the result (to get properties) */
$stmt->store_result();

/* Get the number of rows */
$num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

/* Bind the result to variables */
$stmt->bind_result($id, $first_name, $last_name, $username);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo 'ID: '.$id.'<br>';
    echo 'First Name: '.$first_name.'<br>';
    echo 'Last Name: '.$last_name.'<br>';
    echo 'Username: '.$username.'<br><br>';
}
```

### Example 2 for `$query2` using `get_result()`

```
$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = ?'; 
$id = 5;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query2);
/*
    Binds variables to prepared statement

    i    corresponding variable has type integer
    d    corresponding variable has type double
    s    corresponding variable has type string
    b    corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
*/
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

/* Get the result */
$result = $stmt->get_result();

/* Get the number of rows */
$num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo 'ID: '.$row['id'].'<br>';
    echo 'First Name: '.$row['first_name'].'<br>';
    echo 'Last Name: '.$row['last_name'].'<br>';
    echo 'Username: '.$row['username'].'<br><br>';
}
```

---

### bind_result()

**Pros:**

- Works with outdated PHP versions
- Returns separate variables

**Cons:**

- All variables have to be listed manually
- Requires more code to return the row as array
- The code must be updated every time when the table structure is changed

---

### get_result()

**Pros:**

- Returns associative/enumerated array or object, automatically filled with data from the returned row
- Allows `fetch_all()` method to return all returned rows at once

**Cons:**

- requires MySQL native driver ([mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php))

Comment: OMG, I wish I found this Q&A BEFORE I bound everything to a `$row[]`.  Thank you for the detailed explanation!  One caution; according to the manual get_result() is **Available only with mysqlnd.**

Comment: for all of those where the get_result() method is not working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result

Comment: `bind_result()` seem to work well with an SQL query that use `*`", you just need to know which columns the query returns. What issue do you see here?

Comment: @Arian, I just tried it without `$stmt->store_result();` and it works, why do we need it?

Comment: @Black it stores the properties of the query... like number of rows returned, etc.

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh: great answer. One question, in Example 1, what if no result is found, i.e., there is no id=5 in the db? Will the bind_result() return an error or simply a NULL value? If it is the former would we need an "if" condition? E.g., `if ($num_of_rows>0) { ... bind_result  & fetch ... }`

Answer (score 3):

Examples you can find on the respective manual pages, [`get_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result) and [`bind_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php).

While pros and cons are quite simple:

- `get_result()` is the only sane way to handle results
- yet it could be not always available on some outdated and unsupported PHP version

In a modern web application the data is never displayed right off the query.  The data has to be collected first and only then output has to be started. Or even if you don't follow the best practices, there are cases when the data has to be returned, not printed right away.

Keeping that in mind let's see how to write a code that returns the selected  data as a nested array of associative arrays using both methods.

**`bind_result()`**

```
$query1 = 'SELECT id, first_name, last_name, username FROM `table` WHERE id = ?';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query1);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $first_name, $last_name, $username);
$rows = [];
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $rows[] = [
        'id' => $id,
        'first_name' => $first_name,
        'last_name' => $last_name,
        'username' => $username,
    ];
}
```

and remember to edit this code every time a column is added or removed from the table.

**`get_result()`**

```
$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = ?';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query2);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

and this code remains the same when the table structure is changed.

And there's more.
In case you decide to automate the boring routine of preparing/binding/executing into a neat function that would be called like this

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = ?';
$rows = prepared_select($query, [$id])->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

with `get_result()` it will be quite a plausible task, [a matter of just a few lines](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple). But with `bind_param()` it will will be a tedious quest.

That's why I call the `bind_result()` method "ugly".

Answer (score 2):

`get_result()` is only available in PHP by installing the MySQL native driver (mysqlnd). In some environments, it may not be possible or desirable to install mysqlnd.

Notwithstanding, you can still use mysqli to do `SELECT *` queries, and get the results with the field names - although it is slightly more complicated than using `get_result()`, and involves using PHP's `call_user_func_array()` function. See example at [How to use bind_result() instead of get_result() in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823284/how-to-use-bind-result-instead-of-get-result-in-php/38491087#38491087) which does a simple `SELECT *` query and outputs the results (with the column names) to an HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

Main difference I've noticed is that `bind_result()` gives you error `2014`, when you try to code nested **$stmt inside other $stmt**, that is being **fetched** (without `mysqli::store_result()` ):

> Prepare failed: (2014) Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

### Example:

- Function used in main code.

  ```
  function GetUserName($id)
  {
      global $conn;

      $sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ?";

      if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {

          $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->bind_result($name);

          while ($stmt->fetch()) {
              return $name;
          }
          $stmt->close();
      } else {
          echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
      }
  }
  ```
- Main code.

  ```
  $sql = "SELECT from_id, to_id, content 
          FROM `direct_message` 
          WHERE `to_id` = ?";
  if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {

      $stmt->bind_param('i', $myID);

      /* execute statement */
      $stmt->execute();

      /* bind result variables */
      $stmt->bind_result($from, $to, $text);

      /* fetch values */
      while ($stmt->fetch()) {
          echo "<li>";
              echo "<p>Message from: ".GetUserName($from)."</p>";
              echo "<p>Message content: ".$text."</p>";
          echo "</li>";
      }

      /* close statement */
      $stmt->close();
  } else {
      echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
  }
  ```

Comment: This is actually not entirely true... you're not using `bind_result` correctly

Comment: If you use `$stmt->store_result()` it will allow you to do nested `$stmt` inside other `$stmt`

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh, what am I doing wrong? The documentation about [`mysqli_stmt::bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) on PHP.net doesn't tell me anything about my mistake... Or is it a good practice to use `$stmt->store_result()`?

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh, I thought that if `mysql_store_result ()` sends a large result set, it can become a problem, or am I wrong? Yeah, for this example maybe it's not so important, however... Anyway, thnx for correcting me :)