# PHP: Mysqli prepared statement with "select *"

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

This is how I presently fetch from the DB:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare ( "SELECT fname,lname from $table_name 
where cno >=? LIMIT 50" ))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param ( "i", $cno); 
        $stmt->execute ();
        $stmt->bind_result ($fname,$lname); 
        $arrayUsers = array();

        while ($stmt->fetch())
        {
            if (isset ($fname))
            {
                $arrayUsers[] = array(
                        "fname" => $fname,
                        "lname" => $lname);

}
}
$stmt->close ();
        }
        $mysqli->close ();
```

and it works great.
But if I change my select to `SELECT * from`... my bindings fail.
Does that mean if I have a large number of fields, I will still have to specify each and every field or is there a way to use `select *`?

---- updated ---

```
if (empty($arrayUsers))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return $array;
    }
```

Comment: You should be passing `$table_name` as a parameter as well

Comment: I do, it's in the function parameters, i didnt write that here as it just needlessly takes up space

Comment: When you say bindings are you referring to bind_param or bind_result? bind_result needs to have a variable for each column returned. Make sure it matches the number of columns

Comment: I mean how can I use `select *` instead of `select field1,field2` etc

Comment: @JohnConde - He shouldn't. `SELECT * FROM 'foo'` is not the same as `SELECT * FROM foo`.

Comment: You can always do a `SELECT *`, it is the *conditions* you're binding for.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, check my update. If I do a select * I always get the result of zero.

Comment: You would just not use `bind_result()` in that case, you would use [`get_result()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753262/example-of-how-to-use-bind-result-vs-get-result)

Comment: Aha! That's the answer I was looking for! Thanks! Could you write it in an answer form below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to perform a selection of all of the columns:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
```

You would use PHP's [`get_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) rather than [`bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php).

`bind_result()` is better when you're specifying each column that you're retrieving where `get_result()` will allow you to work with a more generic return of data from your tables.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT *` is never a good idea.

It's better to be explicit.

If you had only 2 columns it would have worked.

That's how `bind_result` works the number variable needs to match the columns.

In addition to that it needs to be in the same order

**Edit:**
Example in pdo:

```
if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare ("SELECT * from `$table_name` where cno >=:cno LIMIT 50" )){
    $stmt->execute([':cno'=>$cno]);
    $arrayUsers = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $stmt->close();
}
$pdo->close();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! If just have a few columns I don't care, I have some tables with a lot more than 2 or 10 and I'm just curious as to how I can get a `select *` instead of explicitly calling each column. Not sure if its even possible...

Comment: Its possible if you know in advance how many column you are fetching and bind all variables. This is dangerous your code will break if you ever add or drop column

Comment: Voted your answer up. I realize the pitfalls of a `select *` but I just wanted to know how it could be done / if it could be done and Jay answered my question. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Ryan yeah thats what you need to achieve it, also PDO can do it easily if you dont mind switching good luck

Comment: Thanks! Got an example with PDO?