# Unable to display a mysqli->bind_result($var) variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I am unable to print out a mysqli binded result.

```
bind_result($variable)
```

Every thing in the code seems to work fine, except the display of the *binded result*.

For example:

If the mysqli query finds 3 results with the search term "Dog", then the following is displayed:

```
 Results: 
 Results: 
 Results:
```

This tells me that everything but the bind_result is working.

The desired display would be would be:

```
Results: Dog
Results: Fog
Results: Log
```

Below is my code:

```
$title = "%".$searchValue."%";

//search by Title
$query = "SELECT Title, ID
      FROM Title
      WHERE Title LIKE ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$title);
$stmt->execute();       

$stmt->bind_result($titleResult); //This is not binding, rest works.

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "Results: ";
    echo $titleResult; //This does not echo, rest works.
    echo "</br>";
}
```

Comment: i think you are not  defining 's' in your code

Comment: example of using ['bind_result' - /18753262/example-of-how-to-use-bind-result-vs-get-result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753262/example-of-how-to-use-bind-result-vs-get-result).

Answer (score 0):

I was selecting two columns.

```
$query = "SELECT Title, ID
```

But only binding one result.

```
$stmt->bind_result($titleResult);
```

Should have been:

```
 $stmt->bind_result($titleResult, $id);
```