# How to fetch data from database using prepare statement in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, php-5.3

I have a database in which I have `user_id` & `associated_id`.There can be multiple `associated_id` for a single `user_id`. Now I want to fetch all the `associated_id`s into a single array. I have tried this method but don't know how to get them in array.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_contacts WHERE user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id);
if ($stmt->execute())
    {
        while ($stmt->fetch())
        {
            //what  to write here 

        }


        //echo var_dump($user);
        $stmt->close();

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to google? http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT associated_id FROM my_contacts WHERE user_id = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $user_id);  // Bind "$user_id" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($associated_id);
        $stmt->fetch();
```

The results will be stored in the `$associated_id` array.

Comment: how do i get the array of elements

Comment: `$assosiated_id` is your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind parameters like this and use `fetchall` method to get all the results in a array

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_contacts WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$stmt->bind_param(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if ($stmt->execute())
    {
      $result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //echo var_dump($user);
        $stmt->close();

    }
```

Comment: Please suggest something relevant to my code.I don't understand PDO & all

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you used mysqli.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_contacts WHERE user_id = ?");
if($stmt->execute()){
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
  if($result->nom_rows > 0){
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       var_dump($row)
     }
  }else{
    echo "Sorry NO data found";
  }
}else{
  echo "Some thing is wrong";
}
```

here you can't used `$stmt->bind_result();` instead of use `$stmt->get_result()`

`$stmt->bind_result();` is only used when you define field in select query

with * you need to used  `$stmt->get_result()`

refer this link for more information

[Example of how to use bind_result vs get_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753262/example-of-how-to-use-bind-result-vs-get-result)