# Json error when connecting my android app to webserver

Tags: php, android, json

I made an android app that sends data to a webhost. I'm having trouble at the login part of my app. Everything seems to work fine when I'm still using localhost. Then I transferred all my php files to a webhost.

When i run my *LoginActivity.java*, it gives me this error:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in **/home/u186950481/public_html/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php** on line **59**

here's my *DB_Functions.php* code:

```php
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            return $user;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user by email and password
     */
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();
            return $user;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check user is existed or not
     */
    public function isUserExisted($email) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email from users WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * @param password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * @param salt, password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }

}

?>
```

Why is this method `mysqli_stmt::get_result()` undefined? Am i missing something? I'm not getting this error on my localhost using WAMP.

Comment: Do you use a different php version on your webserver?

Comment: 5.5 version on both servers local and webhost

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_stmt::get_result() requires mysqlnd

check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

Try to change PHP version to 5.3 and above in your shared hosting server, if that's possible, or use bind_result and fetch instead

Comment: thanks for the response. I checked the php info in my cPanel, mysqlnd is enabled with my php version 5.5. But it's still not working

Comment: Forgive me if I'm kinda desperate but can you teach me how to do that bind_result and fetch on my function getUserByEmailAndPassword? please help me i'm a noob in php.

Comment: check the first answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753262/example-of-how-to-use-bind-result-vs-get-result