# Prepared Statements Select with Variables - php

Tags: php, mysqli

Trying to just set up something to verify that username = password via num_rows = 1.

Trying to use prepared statements, that I have never used before and i'm missing something. Where does the var in bind_results('s',$variable) come from??

Also, its just not working for me.

```
<?php

require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db-connect.php');

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$user = $_POST['username'];
//$user = $mysqli->real_escape_string($user);//
$password = $_POST['password'];
//$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password);//

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?")) {

    $stmt->bind_result('ss', $username);

    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->num_rows;

    echo $result;

    $stmt->close();
}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: Hi!
don't use hardcoded string in the bind_result function. Use always variables.

In your case:
    $sString="ss";

    $stmt->bind_result($sString, $username);

Comment: Okay, thanks, will do that. Any other suggestions to make this work?

Comment: You can check this link, you have many answers to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753262/example-of-how-to-use-bind-result-vs-get-result

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @JayBlanchard at least no mysql deprecation/removal or SQL injection warnings needed for this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems with this:

```
$stmt->bind_result('ss', $username);
```

First, `bind_result` [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php):

> "Binds columns in the result set to variables."

I think you're looking for `bind_param`. [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

> "Bind variables for the parameter markers in the SQL statement that was passed to mysqli_prepare()."

Second, your statement has two parameter markers (`?`), your bind statement indicates two strings (`ss`), but you provide only one variable (`$username`).

Third, `$username` is not what you're getting from `$_POST['username']`. You've assigned that to `$user`. `$username` is for your database connection.

I think it should work for you with this line instead:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $password);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that the bind function was binding something to a new variable that's why I had a different one there! Confused with the prepared statements.

Comment: I would suggest walking through some of the examples in the PHP documentation I linked. They can be helpful to see how it works when you're getting started. Although, to be totally honest what I would _really_ suggest is to use pdo rather than mysqli, because I think it makes it easier to work with prepared statements. Just my opinion, though.