# MySQLi OOP Bind Parameters Error

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli, bind

I am starting with MySQLi, I started with a simple select and it works:

```
$sql = "SELECT nombres, apellidos FROM users WHERE user = 'juan'";
$result = $con->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    print $row->nombres . '<br />';
    print $row->apellidos . '<br />';
}
```

But when I'm trying out using prepared statements have no results displayed... what am I doing wrong?

```
$user = 'juan';
$sql = "SELECT nombres, apellidos FROM users WHERE user = ?";
$result = $con->prepare($sql);
$result->bind_param('s', $user);
$result->execute();

while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    print $row->nombres . '<br />';
    print $row->apellidos . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using fetch in prepared statements is a little bit different. There's another fethcing API for mysqli prepared statements and you'll need to use [`->bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) and [`stmt_fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) for it to work.

```
$result->bind_param('s', $user);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($nombres, $apellidos);

while($result->fetch()){
    print $nombres . '<br />';
    print $apellidos . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An execute will return a `mysqli_statement` object. If you want to process the results of the query like they were a `mysqli_result` object you have to run a `$stmt->get_result()` to convert it to a `mysqli_result` object, then you can process as a `mysqli_result` object with a while loop as you were doing

```
$user = 'juan';
$sql = "SELECT nombres, apellidos FROM users WHERE user = ?";
$stmt= $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    print $row->nombres . '<br />';
    print $row->apellidos . '<br />';
}
```

> Unfortunately this function/method is only available if you have the Native Driver `mysqlnd` installed.

Comment: `->get_result()` another good alternative if this method is available in your env @PatricioCarvajalH

Comment: @PatricioCarvajalH.Ah yes, thanks for reminding me that this is not always available, added a note to that effect

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you. Found those interesting links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753262/example-of-how-to-use-bind-result-vs-get-result

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result

When to use bind_result vs get_result in mysql --> https://arian.io/when-to-use-bind_result-vs-get_result-in-mysql/