# Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in <b>/home/u728597044/public_html/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php</b>

Tags: php, android

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->bind_result($name,$email);
        while($user->fetch_assoc())
        {
        echo $name. "<br>" .$email;
        }
        $stmt->close();

        // verifying user password
        $salt = $user['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $user['encrypted_password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
        // check for password equality
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            // user authentication details are correct
            return $user;
        }
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Error:- Value br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject in [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiEO4.png)
Android
Please help me to find out this error 
Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: try :
boolean error = Boolean.parseBoolean(jObj.getString("error"));

Comment: Why do you use bind_result and not get_result? 
And in the error you can see that the params in bind_result does not match the numbers of fields in your Users table. What's in your Users table?

Comment: in user tables I have id unique id name password email created at and updated at!

Comment: and also I have one entry with name mail and password, error is coming while I am login through device

Comment: so try to make the following: `$stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $pw, $email, $created, $updated)`
that should work as far as I know, you can also read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753262/example-of-how-to-use-bind-result-vs-get-result)

Answer (score 0):

Problem : The `bind_result` warning caused by the number of column resulted by your query doesnt match the parameter you give in bind_result($name,$email) (only 2 param) and i think your query result give greater than 2 column.

Solution : you must know how much column resulted by your sql `SELECT *` and then, add param to the `bind_result()` exactly the same as the number of column resulted.

And use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `fetch_assoc()`.