# How to use mysqli_stmt_affected_rows() with prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

After changing this query to be user with binding parameters, It won't work anymore.

```
    $conectar2 = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE);

    $buscarUsuarioExistente = " SELECT userID, userEmail 
                                FROM usuarios 
                                WHERE userEmail =?
                              ";
                    $usuarioExiste = mysqli_prepare($conectar2,$buscarUsuarioExistente);
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($usuarioExiste, 's', $email);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($usuarioExiste);
                    mysqli_stmt_close($usuarioExiste);

//SI EL MAIL QUE PONE EL USUARIO YA EXISTE EN BASE
    if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($usuarioExiste) != 0) {
            $usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usuarioExiste);
            //como nos devuelve un array, extraemos el primer elemento como string. El array contiene sólo un elemento.
            $userID = array_shift($usuario);
            //si el usuario existe en base, no lo generamos, sino que le agregamos el curso que seleccionó y le asignamos el rol "noAutorizado" hasta no verificar el pago
                    $asignarRol = "INSERT INTO rolesUsuarios 
                                    (userID, nombreRol) 
                                   VALUES 
                                    (?, ?)
                                   ";
                    $noAutorizado = 'noAutorizado';             
                    $asignarRolenBase = mysqli_prepare($conectar2,$asignarRol);
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($asignarRolenBase, 'ss', $userID, $noAutorizado);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($asignarRolenBase);

                    if ($asignarRolenBase) {
                        echo 'Estado "pendiente" del usuario generado.<br>';
                        } 
                        else { 
                            echo 'Error al asignar estado al usuario'.mysqli_error($conectar2).'<br>';
                        }
                    mysqli_stmt_close($asignarRolenBase);

    }
```

The problem seems to be with this: `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($usuarioExiste) != 0` (this is line 45)

Because I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_affected_rows(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt in
>   /home/public_html/inscripcionUsuario.php on line 45

### UPDATE:

I've noticed that I do close it in the line before I call it (thanks Qirel), but moving further down that line, so I don't close it before, gives me this error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   object given

So, with the update:
        $conectar2 = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE);

```
    $buscarUsuarioExistente = " SELECT userID, userEmail 
                                FROM usuarios 
                                WHERE userEmail =?
                              ";
                    $usuarioExiste = mysqli_prepare($conectar2,$buscarUsuarioExistente);
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($usuarioExiste, 's', $email);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($usuarioExiste);

//SI EL MAIL QUE PONE EL USUARIO YA EXISTE EN BASE
    if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($usuarioExiste) != 0) {
            $usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usuarioExiste);
            //como nos devuelve un array, extraemos el primer elemento como string. El array contiene sólo un elemento.
            $userID = array_shift($usuario);
            //si el usuario existe en base, no lo generamos, sino que le agregamos el curso que seleccionó y le asignamos el rol "noAutorizado" hasta no verificar el pago
                    $asignarRol = "INSERT INTO rolesUsuarios 
                                    (userID, nombreRol) 
                                   VALUES 
                                    (?, ?)
                                   ";
                    $noAutorizado = 'noAutorizado';             
                    $asignarRolenBase = mysqli_prepare($conectar2,$asignarRol);
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($asignarRolenBase, 'ss', $userID, $noAutorizado);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($asignarRolenBase);

                    if ($asignarRolenBase) {
                        echo 'Estado "pendiente" del usuario generado.<br>';
                        } 
                        else { 
                            echo 'Error al asignar estado al usuario'.mysqli_error($conectar2).'<br>';
                        }
                    mysqli_stmt_close($asignarRolenBase);
                    mysqli_stmt_close($usuarioExiste);

    }
```

### Update:

I've tried with **mysqli_stmt_num_rows()** 
(`if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($usuarioExiste) != 0)`)

Instead and I've got this error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_stmt, boolean given

Comment: It might be because you close it the line before.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
mysqli_stmt_close($usuarioExiste);
```

You're [closing](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php) the `mysqli_stmt` object which does

> Closes a prepared statement. mysqli_stmt_close() also **deallocates the statement handle**

As to the other question, you're missing a step

```
 $usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usuarioExiste);
```

That won't work because you have a `mysqli_stmt` object, and `mysqli_fetch_assoc` expects a `mysqli_result` object. This gets a bit tricky because you might not have the MySQL Native Driver installed (that's a server config). If you do, you can fix it like this

```
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($usuarioExiste);
$usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

If that function is undefined you'll have to use the much clunkier [mysqli_stmt_bind_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) and assign variables. The examples here require a lot of recoding on your part, but you can see some examples over at [Example of how to use bind_result vs get_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753262/example-of-how-to-use-bind-result-vs-get-result)

Comment: I know that the database exists and the credetials are ok, but this error now could be because it cannot connect? `Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean` I also get a mysql error `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

Comment: I think you might need to ask a new question at this point. We're way beyond the original scope