# Getting results of statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have made this example code:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","password","xxx");

$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT name, password FROM persons WHERE name=? LIMIT 1");

$statement->bind_param('s', "kevin");

$statement->execute();

if($statement->num_rows){

$statement->bind_result($dbname, $dbpassword);

$statement->free_result();

};

echo $dbname;
echo $dbpass;
```

How can use/get $dbname and $dbpassword directly without using something like:

```
while($statement->fetch()){
    echo $dbname;
}
```

I want to use $dbname and dbpassword directly.
What is the best approach? What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Change `$num_rows` to `num_rows`

Comment: @SuperDJ Indeed thats a mistake thanks.

Comment: But how to get and use the single row of results. maybe fetch_row or something?

Comment: Did you try Google?

Comment: @Your Commen Sense Of course, but get to many confusing results

Comment: Well, mysqli *is* confusing, so you should use PDO. But still, what's exactly confusing about results you get?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Wel, I always used the procedural but now i thought, i'll switch to oop. But this leaves me confused. I just need to query the db an get 1 row of result. Then, I would like to use this result as simple as possible... I hoped i could use 'bind_result' to get the result in $dbname an $dbpassword an the just use those to variables further in my php code... But it seems that its not the case

Comment: @YourCommonSense And for the moment i dont get any result...

Comment: @YourCommonSense I added some code to show what i want. Let's say i want to echo $dbname and $dbpass;

Comment: why don't you want to use the while loop to get the result?

Comment: maybe interesting? show how to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753262/example-of-how-to-use-bind-result-vs-get-result

Comment: why don't you use fetch()?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Are you willing to rapidly alter my code so it works with fetch? For the moment my mind is like the far west...

Comment: @YourCommonSense Like in this treath: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753262/example-of-how-to-use-bind-result-vs-get-result they use a while statement, but i dont just need to echo the result, i"ll need to access them troughout my code... Do I need to put them in variables using the while loop? This seems so overkill for just one row of result

Comment: @RyanVincent I'll go to that article once again... but why do i need the while statement for one row of results. Do I need to put them in variables using the while loop? This seems so overkill for just one row of result

Comment: you do't need while statement for one row of results. but you still need to fetch

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ah, and please tell me how.. $row = $statement->fetch()? --- with $row['$dbname'] or with $row['dbname'] or just with $row['name']

Comment: imo, The nice point about using a a while loop is that you can use the same code everywhere for one or or many rows. The overhead of the while loop is minimal. I wouldn't bother with the `num_rows` value, as it is more confusing than not, and just keep a count in the 'while loop' but that is just me..

Comment: @RyanVincent You pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

I needed to store the result (Store the result (to get properties))

I needed to fetch the result (Fetch results from a prepared statement into the bound variables) Gladfully without a while loop.

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","password","xxx");

$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT name, password FROM persons WHERE name=? LIMIT 1");

$statement->bind_param('s', "kevin");

$statement->execute();

$statement->store_result(); // this is what I was missing

if($statement->num_rows){

    $statement->bind_result($dbname, $dbpassword);

    $statement->fetch(); // this is what I was missing

    $statement->free_result();

    echo $dbname;

    echo $dbpass;

};
```