# Need help in showing data from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have a table[info] like this

```
+---+-------+---------------+
|id | cost  | place         |
+---+-------+---------------+
|1  | 2000  | Dhaka         | 
|2  | 1000  | Cox's Bazar   |
+---+-------+---------------+
```

Now I'm using this query to show these data

```
$a_place = $_POST['place'];
query = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE place = '$a_place'";
```

It works fine when I am searching for Dhaka, but it is not working for Cox's Bazar. Maybe for this > `'`

Now what can I do? Please help!

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements!

Comment: You have to escape the inputstring

Comment: Use prepared statements, which will handle the escaping of quotes automatically.

Comment: or replace `'` and then put it for condition

Comment: Can you guys pleas write the code for me? :/

Comment: you can add \' for Cox\'s Bazar

Answer (score 1):

### try this

```
$a_place = str_replace($_POST['place'],"'","''");

query = "SELECT * from info WHERE place = '".$a_place."'";
```

### Edit

creating table and insert data

[image]

as you see the data ise like yours.

and If I select like mine the output is **true**

[image]

Comment: It's not working. When I'm using this it showing me no results :/

Comment: can you try this: query = "SELECT * from info WHERE place = 'Cox''s Bazar'";

this should work

Comment: Yes it works @ErsinGülbahar. But user will not search for Cox''s Bazar, na? They will search for Cox's Bazar. :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help for a start:

```
// prepare and bind
$a_place = $_POST['place'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT country FROM info WHERE place = '?'");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $a_place);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows){
  $stmt->bind_result($country);
  $stmt->fetch();
  $stmt->free_result();
  echo $country;
};
?>
```

and see this post:
[Getting results of statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140462/getting-results-of-statement)

(remeber that select * is bad practice)