# get_result() doesn't work on my web host

Tags: php, prepared-statement, mysqlnd

My webhost server is using libmysqlclient as the driver.
Currently the only way that they can support MySQLND is via a VPS / dedicated server.
And i don't want that.

I'm using php 7 btw...

This is a similar code that i am using.

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name,email,keylog FROM user WHERE email=? AND name=? 
    AND keylog =? ");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $em, $nme, $k);

    $em = 'user@mail.com';
    $nme = 'joeDoe';
    $k ='123';
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if($row = $result->fetch_array()){
       $nameIs = $row['name'];
    }
    echo $nameIs;
```

I know i can use PDO, but i coded my whole project this way.
I searched for alternatives and didn't find anything that works. 
What should i do?

Comment: From the manual on `get_result()` - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php *"MySQL Native Driver Only 
Available only with mysqlnd."*

Comment: *"I searched for alternatives and didn't find anything that works."* - They're out there, believe me. Google'd edit: For instance http://stackoverflow.com/q/18753262/1415724 which is more than likely a duplicate.

Comment: Huge thx Fred  !

Comment: You're welcome James.