# MySQL prepared statements throwing error in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

This is the code to connect to my database. I am sure the username, password and database name are correct.

```
$Myconn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->DBname);
```

This is code for prepare statement:

```
$query =$Myconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `AD` WHERE name=?");
$query->bind_param('s', $AD_Name);
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
$query->bind_result($id, $name, $price);
```

and I am sure that I sent `$AD_Name` correctly, as well as my query.

I used AMPPS and it was working while using my code.

My problem is that my result is always `null` when i print `$id` or  `$name` or  `$price`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing

```
$query->bind_result($id, $name, $price);
```

use

```
$query->fetch();
```

Comment: Glad to help mate

Answer (score 2):

Ali Rasheed is right that you should use `fetch()` after doing a `bind_result()`, but there is a bigger issue here. You cannot use `bind_result()` with `SELECT * ...`. It will not work properly because `bind_result()` will not know the order of the selected elements and thus it will not know which variable should get which value. Instead, you should revise to something like:

```
$query =$Myconn->prepare("SELECT id, name, price FROM `AD` WHERE name=?");
$query->bind_param('s', $AD_Name);
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
$query->bind_result($id, $name, $price);
$query->fetch();
```

*Substitute the column names as necessary of course.*

You can see a good explanation about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18753263/2694511