# need the result of mysqli query as a json array from this phpscript

Tags: php, json

this  is my php script

```
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') 
{

$qry_check="SELECT * FROM `tb_user`";

$stmt = $con->prepare($qry_check);

if ($stmt->execute()){

     echo "Success";

}}

else 
     echo "Fail";

}
?>
```

when i run this query on my mysqli online server i get result which i have attached below i need this result as a json array when i call this json url, hanks in advance,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsD09.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsD09.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON encode MySQL results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results)

Comment: **PDO** != **mysqli**

Comment: can anyone help with code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') 
    {
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_user");

             if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    $users = array();
                    $user=$stmt->get_result();
                     while($row = $user->fetch_assoc()){
                        $users[]=$row;
                     }

                     $stmt->close();                       

                echo json_encode($users);
            }
}

?>
```

or use this code. Add your remaining columns in this code for full result

```
    <?php

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') 
    {
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT user_id, category_id FROM tb_user");

             if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    $users = array();
                    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $category_id);
                      while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                         $user["user_id"] = $user_id;
                        $user["category_id"] = $category_id;
                        $users[] = $user;
                     }

                     $stmt->close();                       

                echo json_encode($users);
            }
}

?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Comment: i have added two parathesis at end now it shows error like this... Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Comment: try this one please

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Comment: please do check my database screenshot

Comment: you can avoid this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: use this for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753262/example-of-how-to-use-bind-result-vs-get-result?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: if you can help me with code it will be better bcoz i have already read it

Comment: am an android developer and i have just minute knowledge in php

Comment: added some edits using bind_result . please look into it

Answer (score 0):

I already mention in comment that mysqli != PDO. But I thnk you don't get it.

You are initializing connection with `mysqli` then doing all process with `PDO` so you don't get result

```
<?php  

    $servername = HOST;
    $username = USER;
    $password = PASS;
    $dbname = DB;
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') 
    {
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_user");

             if ($stmt->execute()) 
             {
                    $users = array();                        
                     while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        $users[]=$row;
                     }

                     $stmt->close();                       

                echo json_encode($users);
            }
}

?>
```