# Using prepared statement with update set, immediately following a while loop in php

Tags: php, prepared-statement

When I try to change the code from the first block to second block, I get an error message saying it returned false. This is always how I use prepared statements for all the other methods (delete, insert, like). I believe the while loop is causing the issue.

This code below code works (but probably not SQLI injection proof):

```
$id=$_GET['edit'];    
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id=$id");
```

This code below gets an error message basically saying that it returned false:

```
$result = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id=?");
$result->bind_param('i', $_GET['edit']);
$result->execute();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id= $row['id'];
    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    $last_name = $row['last_name'];
    $position = $row['position'];
```

This code below I used for a search bar and it works 100%. However, for update it gets the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array():

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
```

Comment: so what's the *real* error here? Edit: @u_mulder the OP deleted. I know you can see this message *lol!*

Comment: Please, read a manual. It will tell you difference between direct query and prepared.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner real error is the `$result` is not `mysqli_stmt` (

Comment: Correct. $result = $con->prepare is what I meant.

Comment: while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))  is what I used for a search. Did not use mysqli_stmt but will look into it.

Comment: Yeah. fetch_array is what I used for my search bar which is working. I bet if I use the foreach loop after it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer:

```
if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id=?")){
    $id=$_GET['edit']; //the ID is in the url
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$id= $row['id'];
$first_name = $row['first_name'];
$last_name = $row['last_name'];
$position = $row['position'];
?>
```

Also, after reading [Example of how to use bind_result vs get_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753262/example-of-how-to-use-bind-result-vs-get-result?noredirect=1&lq=1), I concluded that using get_result is the easiest method. But that is up to the person/employer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
$con    = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$result = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id=?");
$qryres = $result->execute('i', $_GET['edit']); //$result->bind_param('i', $_GET['edit']);
$row    = ($qryres) ? $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) : array(); 
$con    = null;
//You can then loop over the row
```