# How to print all the results of a table without the need to print variable by variable?

Tags: php, mysqli

Some easier way to print all those results in a two column table with the respective column name of the data table, without the need to be printing variable by variable.

I'm using mysqli object oriented PHP, not using PDO, not this please: (`fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`).

```
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result(
        $id_logtrama, $fechaHora, $idCliente,
        $idEquipo, $statusGlobal, $temp,
        $tempAmb, $hrelAmb, $presion,
        $termopar1, $termopar2, $volt_fase1,
        $amps_fase1, $frec_fase1, $fpot_fase1,
        $volt_fase2, $amps_fase2, $frec_fase2, $fpot_fase2, 
        $volt_fase3, $amps_fase3, $frec_fase3, $fpot_fase3, 
        $status_temp, $status_tempAmb, $status_hrelAmb, $status_presion,
        $status_termopar1, $status_termopar2, $status_volt_fase1,
        $status_amps_fase1, $status_frec_fase1, $status_fpot_fase1,
        $status_volt_fase2, $status_amps_fase2, $status_frec_fase2,
        $status_fpot_fase2, $status_volt_fase3, $status_amps_fase3,
        $status_frec_fase3, $status_fpot_fase3, $trama
    );
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {}
```

Comment: Are you SELECTing multiple rows or just a simgle row

Comment: @RiggsFolly What happens is that I want to avoid doing all this: https://jsfiddle.net/24vp8uca/ it's possible?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Multiple rows https://jsfiddle.net/8gc5b2ds/

Comment: @RiggsFolly Exactly, that way several records and multiple columns as indicated.

Comment: Bind_result with 50 variables? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is one row with lots of columns, but even if you have multiple rows, get the result set using `$res = $stmt->store_result();` and then you can get the row as a assoc array and process each column with its name and value in an inner foreach loop like this

```
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->store_result();
?>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
<?php
    # Fetch each row from resultset
    while ( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() ){
        # for each row process each column
        foreach ($row as $name => $val ) {

            echo "
                <tr>
                    <td width='30%'><label>$name</label></td>
                    <td width='70%'>$val</td>
                </tr>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using this method is not necessary any additional library in mysql?

Comment: All functions are part of the `MYSQLI` extension.

Comment: I mean this problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753262/example-of-how-to-use-bind-result-vs-get-result requires MySQL native driver (mysqlnd)?

Comment: So you are saying you cannot use `store_result()`?

Comment: No to this: `fetch_assoc` should I have that driver or not?

Comment: And it `mysqli_result::fetch_all()` that is `Available only with mysqlnd.`

Comment: That's what I was trying to tell you, whether it requires that or not.

Comment: @Valentina Why would you be using mysqli that is not compiled with mysqlnd? All modern versions of PHP should be compiled with mysqlnd