# PHP - prepared statements and json_encode

Tags: php, prepared-statement, json

I want to create a php script using prepared statements to query a table in my database and return the results in json format. I have a table of doctors and i want to return the doctors of a given speciality. I have a version of the script that doesn't use prepared statements that works fine. But when i use prepared statements my script doesn't work.

**Non - prepared statements version:**

```
<?php
// include database constants
require_once("../config/config.php");             

// create db connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

$speciality = $_POST['speciality'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `doctors` WHERE speciality='$speciality'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die("Error executing the query");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output[]= $row;    
}
print(json_encode($output));

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

**prepared statements version:**

```
<?php
// include database constants
require_once("../config/config.php");             

// create db connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

$speciality = $_POST['speciality'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `doctors` WHERE speciality=?";
if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($query)){
    $stmt -> bind_param("s", $speciality);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $result = $stmt -> get_result();

    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $output[]= $row;    
    }

    print(json_encode($output));
    $stmt -> close();

} else {
    echo $mysqli->error;
    echo "no entry found";
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

What am i doing wrong? I don't get a mysqli error which means that the problem is after the execution of the query but i just don't know what it is.

Edit: What i mean by saying it doens't work is that i don't get anything back. The html body of the page after the execution is completely empty. On the other hand if i use the other script i posted (without prepared statements) i get the expected result.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does it return an empty object? Is it missing rows? What?

Comment: put a `var_dump(result)` after `get_result()`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol i dont get anything back. The html body is completely empty.

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Comment: @koukouloforos - try this Hope it helps. `$result = $stmt -> use_result();`

Comment: @koukouloforos - +1 - I think this is a good question and it was my question too.(I searched and find the answer). But I don't know why Some puts down votes WITHOUT giving the reason??!!??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATED:

Use this:

```
/* bind result variables */
$stmt->bind_result($col1,$col2,$col3,$col4);

/* fetch values */
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $output[]=array($col1,$col2,$col3,$col4);
}
```

Instead. Hope it helps.

anyone please give reason of putting downvote.

Comment: your welcome.(-: you know. I don't know why other gave me down vote without reason.(-:

Answer (score 2):

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and then look at HTML body again. Most likely get_result is not supported but I hate to guess.

Comment: Here is the result:  Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result(). So what i do know?

Comment: +1 a good answer. You should set error reporting `E_ALL` when you want to debug your codes.

Comment: @koukouloforos - so why you are not using `use_result` instead? please check my answer.

Comment: I get the same error with use_result. Check my commend to your answer.

Comment: @imsiso you rather should have it ALWAYS

Comment: What you mean always? (I know you are right) but I was with the OP and I meant you should not let your errors be displayed in production mode. But I think I have a misunderstanding in what error_reporting is doing.

Comment: @imsiso as you can see, there is another setting responsible for fdisplaying

Comment: @YourCommonSense - what do you think about my answer is it wrong?

Comment: @imsiso i think its wrong to delete your answer and write another

Comment: @YourCommonSense - I know but what should I do then? I have posted an answer and some one had put a downvote with no reason. What should I do? I had posted and answer which had been accepted but 2 person had give it downvote without any reason. what should I do in such situations? thanks.

Comment: @imsiso just stick to your first answer. You can edit it freely, while deleting and writing it back would be surely considered as cheating. And also try to refrain from posing absolutely pointless answers, like your first one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - again you are right I will undelete them now. The first one was not a good answer but please take a look at the second and third answer which are correct and some one had put -1.(now the new answer (accepted one) has 0=1-1) You are so experianced. What should I do this has happend to me for a complete correct and accepted answer. what's going on? - again thanks.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - did you see my last comment?

Comment: @imsiso it's the very cheating with deleting answers I told you before. Anyway, you are too much concerned in such trifle things. Just let it go.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your version of PHP is compatible with the method

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: `# php -v
PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u4 (cli) (built: Aug 23 2013 14:37:41) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies`

Comment: Here is a solution to the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result

Comment: Thanks it helped. I ended up not using mysqlnd. I used bind_result and  fetch as shown in the answer by @imsisco

Answer (score 0):

To get data as associative array you can do as follow:

```
$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);
$rows = [];
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $rows[]=array("col1"=>$col1, "col2"=>$col2);
}
```