# PHP undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_results()

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

On backend I have rest api and I call `v1/task` with ajax to get all user tasks

I have:

```
public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $tasks = $stmt->get_results();
        $stmt->close();
        return $tasks;
    }
```

but I got error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_results() in <b>/home/agroagro/public_html/agroMobile/include/DbHandler.php</b> on line <b>281</b><br />
```

Here is my console screen: [image]

How I can solv ethis problem? Any replacment for this function?

Comment: most likely because you don't have the `mysqlnd` in your environment.

Comment: how I can replace get_result function with BIND and FETCH ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/CdUKd9R.png

Answer (score 1):

I think small mistake in your function

$tasks = $stmt->get_results();

it should be

```
$tasks = $stmt->get_result();
```

Or try by this way

```
$stmt->bind_result();
$tasks = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in <b>/home/agroagro/public_html/agroMobile/include/DbHandler.php

Comment: How I can replace get_result with BIND and FETCH

Comment: but please write answer without get_result function ... I will try to restart apache

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/CdUKd9R.png

Comment: Check your php version also the $stmt->get_result() function works from PHP 5.3,
also if you select the $stmt->bind_result(); method then you have to specify the column names as a parameter.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result

Comment: PHP 5.4.0 ... please write answer for my code , how to specify column names... sory about trivial question I'm super beginer

Comment: when I change y code with your from answer I get: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in <b>/home/agroagro/public_html/agroMobile/v1/index.php</b> on line <b>155</b><br />

Comment: and again dont work ...

Comment: Un comment this line "extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll in php.ini;" from your php.ini file and try with  $stmt->get_result(); function.

Ofcourse you get the Call to a member function issue while using $stmt->bind_result(); thats because there is empty parameters, you have to pass the column names as a parameters, if you want to fetch all the columns then you have to pass all the columns as a parameters.