# Android Login and Sign up using PHP and SQLIte

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

I am following this [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) link but in eclipse my code is below

**1.)LoginActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import info.androidhive.loginandregistration.R;     
import info.androidhive.loginandregistration.app.AppConfig;
import info.androidhive.loginandregistration.app.AppController;
import info.androidhive.loginandregistration.helper.SQLiteHandler;
import info.androidhive.loginandregistration.helper.SessionManager;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnLinkToRegister;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                // Check for empty data in the form
                if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    // login user
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * function to verify login details in mysql db
     * */
    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Now store the user in SQLite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**2.)RegisterActivity**

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnRegister;
    private Button btnLinkToLogin;
    private EditText inputFullName;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString().trim();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    registerUser(name, email, password);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Function to store user in MySQL database will post params(tag, name,
     * email, password) to register url
     * */
    private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                              final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        // User successfully stored in MySQL
                        // Now store the user in sqlite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Launch login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                RegisterActivity.this,
                                LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**3.)login.php**

```
<?php



require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // get the user by email and password
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

    if ($user != false) {
        // use is found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required post params is missing
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**4.)register.php**

```
<?php



require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check if user is already existed with the same email
    if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
        // user already existed
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // create a new user
        $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**4.)DB_Functions.php**

```
<?php



class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            return $user;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user by email and password
     */
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();
            return $user;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check user is existed or not
     */
    public function isUserExisted($email) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email from users WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * @param password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * @param salt, password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }

}

?>
```

**It's showing following error-**

E/Volley(1939): [1412] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for ..example.com/app/login.php
E/RegisterActivity(1939): Login Error: null

E/Volley(1939): [1413] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for ...example.com/app/register.php
E/RegisterActivity(1939): Registration Error: null

Comment: `RegisterActivity` is working?

Comment: @Amy  Yes.. its working but when first i register through app it shows the register  error which i mentioned above...when i click again after few seconds it shows user already exits and the table gets populated in the database which i have entered while regitering and when i try to login toast shows nothing and i am also unable to login also.

Comment: do you mean its working sometimes and sometime not?

Comment: @Amy it populates the database with the user credentials but it shows the error in eclipse Unexpected response code 500 for ...example.com/app/register.php E/RegisterActivity(1939): Registration Error: null  .......and on same time i click again it eclipse shows --Register Response: {"error":true,"error_msg":"User already existed with r"}...and when i try to login i am unable to login

Comment: you are using localhost or live server for this?

Comment: @Amy i am using live server

Comment: can you provide me server URL?

Comment: Please delete yout last comment for sicurity purpose

Comment: is `created_at` and `updated_at` getting reflected in DB?

Comment: I think it might `created_at` and `updated_at` is null in db

Comment: @Amy created at is reflected properly but updated_at is Null

Comment: that is the actual problem

Comment: If the server responds with an error 500 read the error log of the server. There will be a clear message what's wrong.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider its showing ---- E/Volley(1939): [1413] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://xyz.url/xyz/login.php
 E/RegisterActivity(1939): Login Error: null

Comment: That's not the log of the webserver.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider its showing----PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/xyx/public_html/app/DB_Functions.php on line 42
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/xyz/public_html/app/DB_Functions.php on line 61

Comment: There you are. That function was introduced in PHP 5.3. What PHP version are you using on the server?

Comment: Also note that this functions is only available if you use [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php), which is not always enabled by default.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider i have seen just now its PHP 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in database all values getting reflected properly

i.e. `unique_id`
`name`
`email`
`password`
`created_at`
`updated_at`

Comment: @ShreyaSrivastava comment this line and try `$response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];`

Comment: its showing--- E/Volley(1939): [1413] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://xyz.kom/xyz/login.php
 E/RegisterActivity(1939): Login Error: null

Answer (score 0):

The error in your server log indicates that the function [`get_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) does not exist in your mysqli statement object. There are two possible reasons for this:

1. You are using a PHP version older than 5.3
2. You don't have [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) enabled in PHP, which is required for this function.

Depending on the reasons you have three options:

1. Update PHP to 5.3 or newer
2. Enable the module in the php.ini file

If you can't do either of these, you can change your code to work without that function, as described in this question:

[Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result)

Comment: i have seen my php version is 5.3 and i have also enabled mysqlnd in the settings but still its not working

Comment: If you enabled mysqlnd (and restarted your server) you should get a different error message in the server log.

Comment: according yo your php code changements its shows---PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/xyzr/public_html/app/DB_Functions.php on line 65

Comment: I already removed my code from the answer, I noticed it didn't work. See the linked question for a working solution without that function.

Comment: Sir, i am not able to do it i have mentioned my DB_Functions.php code in my question please could u help .

Answer (score 0):

HTTP error 500 means internal server error. So, I would start by looking at the log files of the webserver you are connecting to. There is most likley some error with your php logic, database connection, permissions or credentials.

**Edit**: Noticed your comments now about your log and the *get_result* function

> HP Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in
>   /home/xyx/public_html/app/DB_Functions.php on line 42 PHP Fatal error:
>   Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in
>   /home/xyz/public_html/app/DB_Functions.php on line 61

The *get_result* function requires the mysqlnd driver. If this is not installed on your webserver you should stick to *bind_result* and *fetch*.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Here's some more information clearly stating that the *get_result* function is only available with the [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) driver: Please read the user notes for this method:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem,

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/xyz/a_pp/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php on line 64

Here is how i was able to fix it:
`Turn on nd_mysqli and mysqlnd`and `Turn off mysqli`
i'm using PHP 7.1

Answer (score -1):

compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

just update your volley library

Answer (score -1):

i think you should change $_POST with $_GET in register.php. hope it will works!