# PHP: Fetching records after mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is an elementary question, but I am finding it very confusing. Earlier I used to bind the results and fetch them using while loop. I am using * in the sql statement, hence the doubt. Here is the code:

```
$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $mysql->prepare($sql);
$prm = $_POST['txt'];
$stmt->bind_param("i",$prm);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {

}
```

There are around 20 columns in the table, hence I want to avoid including all column names in the sql.
How do I echo out all the columns of each record?

Comment: So keep using `while`

Comment: If you want to fetch Colum of your Rows you can use `distinct` in the place of * and use while Query again to Fetch all records

Comment: What about `foreach($row as $fieldName => $value){ ... }`?

Answer (score 1):

For `bind_result` you have to write your query as

```
 $sql = "SELECT column1,column2 FROM mytable WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $mysql->prepare($sql);
    $prm = $_POST['txt'];
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $prm);
    $stmt->execute();
/*bind your result*/
    $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
/* fetch values */
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2);
        }
    }
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

**Updated**

Using `fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $mysql->prepare($sql);
    $prm = $_POST['txt'];
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $prm);
    $stmt->execute();
/*bind your result*/

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
/* fetch values */
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
           printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["row1"], $row["row2"]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Saty, this will be my last resort. I want to avoid lengthy lines of column names and their bindings.

Comment: So where did you invent a `$result` variable

Answer (score 1):

```
        $mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = ?";
        $stmt = $mysql->prepare($sql);
        $prm = $_POST['txt'];
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$prm);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->store_result(); //store_result() 

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) { //Uses the stored result and counts the rows.

        while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
                //And here, the answer-object is turned into an array-(object)
                // which can be worked with nicely.
                //It loops trough all entries in the array.
        }

        }
```

Comment: Shailesh, I get this error ->  PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given

Comment: So where did you invent a `$result` variable

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_result()` **instead of** `store_result()`, and then use result object's `->num_rows` property to check if it returns any row or not, like this:

```
$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $mysql->prepare($sql);
$prm = $_POST['txt'];
$stmt->bind_param("i",$prm);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        // your code

    }
}
```

Comment: Rajdeep, I am getting this error-> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Comment: @sridhar Which version of PHP are you using? Please note that `mysqli_stmt :: get_result` is available only with mysqlnd driver. Refer [this stack overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8343970/5517143) and see the first comment of OP.

Comment: php 5.5. It looks like I will have to type out all column names and bind them individually and use fetch() after all.

Comment: @sridhar Is this line **extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll** commented or uncommented in **php.ini** file?

Comment: The mysqlnd.dll is part of core PHP, so it does not need an `extension...` statement to load it in PHP5.5. Run a `phpinfo()` and you should see `MYSQLND` listed there if that is the library being used