# Query doesn't work on my Raspberry Pi 2B

Tags: php, mysql, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to get my raspberry working like a webserver.

It all works, except the queries of my mysql  database. The values are correct, the query is correct and my database works fine.

But when I want to get information from my database with PHP it gives an empty result.

The code:

```
<?php

$dbCon = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$Query = "SELECT * FROM `machineuptime`";

if($stmt = $dbCon->prepare($Query))
{
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $ArrayData2[] = $row;
    }
}

echo "this is de first row of the array: " . $ArrayData2[0]['ID'] . ". Thats nice!";
?>
```

the result:

> this is de first row of the array: . Thats nice!

Even when I use the query in phpmyadmin, it gives the values back, so the Query isn't wrong.

So how can I solve this issue?

*Edit:*

The error that I get is.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /var/www/html/Stramit/index.php on line 59
```

Comment: Even when I dont, this code works on my laptop...

Comment: try enabling error reporting add this: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', -1);` to the top of the php part

Comment: you didn't end your query with " - is that a typo, or actually in the source?

Comment: > Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /var/www/html/Stramit/index.php on line 59 is the error what I get now.....

Comment: @FranzGleichmann typo. srry bout that

Comment: look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8343970/5396496)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't close the query at:

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM `machineuptime`;
```

change it to:

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM `machineuptime`";
```

also for the error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /var/www/html/Stramit/index.php on line 59

look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8343970/5396496)

Look at the user notes for http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

It requires mysqlnd driver.Make sure you have that driver installed. If you do not have them installed use BIND_RESULT & FETCH

uncommented the extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll in php.ini; and restarted Apache2.2 and MySQL services. says it in the comment of the answer.

Here is the link to the driver: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php

after you have installed it you should be able to use `$stmt->get_result();` ofcourse reboot your raspberry pi.

*Note: your php version must be above php 5.3.0*

Comment: it isn't fetch_assoc it is get_result and I will add the links for it.

Comment: Ye I found a how to install the mysqlnd driver in here: http://blog.ahughes.org/?p=602. It works now. Thanks for the help

Comment: Good, no problem mate. Always glad to help:D