# Error While Fetching Rows From mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code running on PHP server, but I am stuck with following issue

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM vehicle_model");
$stmt->execute();
//grab a result set
$resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
//pull all results as an associative array
$result = $resultSet->fetch_all();
$stmt->close();
return $result;
```

I have created the connection like below

```
new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

I am having PHP version 5.5.9 and Server type: MySQL

**Error:**

> [Mon Apr 11 19:33:46.033855 2016] [:error] [pid 10259] [client 223.190.77.90:50531] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /var/www/html/include/VehicleModelHandler.php on line 19

I am stuck for almost 2 hours if any one can point out what is happening wrong that would be a great help.

Comment: Check if mysqld(client) are instaled

Comment: The insertion and updating of other table are happening

Comment: Here is relative question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result . Seems like @rray is right

Answer (score 0):

Document clearly explains how to use $stmt function..

please refer this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php