# Convert method get_result()

Tags: php, mysql

How do I convert this block of PHP code so that it won't require me to install mysqlnd driver to my server:

```
public function getAllChatRooms() {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM chat_rooms");
        $stmt->execute();
        $tasks = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();
        return $tasks;
    }
```

I am trying to upload my backend files to the server. But unfortunately, my server doesn't have mysqlnd driver so I'm getting an error of undefined method for get_result().

Comment: In all cases, PHP does not ship with an inbuilt database driver, you need to have at least one database driver, mysqlnd, mysqli or PDO

Comment: my server might have PDO/mysqli

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11135291/689579

Comment: @Sean My query selects all columns, what will I put as paramters in bind_result? How do I return the $tasks?