# JSON works on localhost but not on server -mysqlndrivers are updated

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, getjson

I am creating a web service for android and PHP registration process. 
I am following this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

**The Issue is: My JSON works on localhost but not on a server. On a server it gives me this error but it stores the data on database successfully.**

Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/pmc/public_html/zeusonline.me/zeus/include/DB_Functions.php on line 45

**and the line 45 is:**

$user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

Code samples->

**Register.php file**

```
<?php
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("status" => TRUE);

if (isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['email']) &&  
isset($_GET['country']) && isset($_GET['phone_number']) && 
isset($_GET['password']) && isset($_GET['lat']) && isset($_GET['lon'])) {

// receiving the post params
$username = $_GET['username'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$country = $_GET['country'];
$phone_number = $_GET['phone_number'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lon = $_GET['lon'];


// check if user is already existed with the same email
if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
    // user already existed
    $response["status"] = FALSE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else if ($db->isUserExisted($phone_number)) {
    // user already existed
    $response["status"] = FALSE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $phone_number;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
    // create a new user
    $user = $db->storeUser($username, $email, $country , $phone_number, 
$password, $lat, $lon);
    if ($user) {
        // user stored successfully
        $response["status"] = TRUE;
        $response["user"]["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["username"] = $user["username"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["country"] = $user["country"];
        $response["user"]["phone_number"] = $user["phone_number"];
        $response["user"]["country"] = $user["country"];
        $response["user"]["height"] = $user["height"];
        $response["user"]["weight"] = $user["weight"];
        $response["user"]["is_number_verified"] = 
 $user["is_number_verified"];
        $response["user"]["is_safe"] = $user["is_safe"];
        $response["user"]["is_login"] = $user["is_login"];
        $response["user"]["lat"] = $user["lat"];
        $response["user"]["lon"] = $user["lon"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["Status"] = False;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
  }
} else {
$response["Status"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters are missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**DB_Functions.php file**

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

private $conn;

// constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $db = new Db_Connect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}

/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($username, $email, $country, $phone_number, 
$password, $lat, $lon) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $height = 0; 
    $weight = 0;
    $is_number_verified = False;
    $is_safe = True;
    $is_login = False;
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (unique_id, username, 
email, country, phone_number, password, salt, height, weight, 
is_number_verified, is_safe, is_login, lat, lon, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, 
?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,NOW())");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssss", $uuid, $username, $email, $country, 
$phone_number, $encrypted_password, $salt, $height, $weight, 
$is_number_verified, $is_safe, $is_login, $lat, $lon);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone_number 
= ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $phone_number);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
?>
```

**The URL for testing :**

http://pakmanzil.com/zeusonline.me/zeus/register.php?username=bilal&email=bi@gmail.com&country=england&phone_number=03333524145&password=123&lat=0.0&lon=0.0

Change the email and phone_number to make it works please :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined method mysqli\_stmt::get\_result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result)

Comment: Huge security issues here, you're sending **clear** password in `GET`! I would recommand you to use `POST` and to hash your password before sending, storing or sending clear passwords is really dangerous!

Comment: @MarkusLaire mysqlndrivers are updated on my server already.

Comment: @Vuldo Thanks, I will look into it, but can you tell me why this code is not working on server

Comment: Do you have  the same PHP version on local and production?

Comment: @Vuldo on localhost i have 7.0.6 and on server I have 5.5. i tries to change 5.5 to 7.0(thats maximum on my server) but still same problem

Comment: You need the same version to be sure that there is a full compatibility, are you sure that you really installed the same version?

Comment: https://s31.postimg.org/uligfz1yz/php.png 
this is the settings on my server for 5.5 .........

Comment: anybody here? who can solve this issue ?