# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() being enabled mysqlnd

Tags: php, mysqlnd, godaddy-api

I am getting an error in my rest api while calling `$stmt->get_result()`.

> PHP Fatal error:
>   Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

The previous questions about this suggest to enable mysqlnd driver. I have done that in my godaddy account, but I'm still getting the error.

```
public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $tasks = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    return $tasks;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more code.

Comment: Please check out the code @Nguai al

Comment: I've checked it. It says mysqlnd not enabled. When I've already selected mysqlnd. as you can check [here](http://abtsgh.com/Capture1.PNG)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result

Comment: Turning the mysqlnd doesn't help. As I shared the image link. I think I'll have to contact godaddy. @Mattia Dinosaur

Comment: have you restart the php-fpm ?you should use phpinfo() to check whether you have enable mysqlnd

Comment: how to restart php-fpm at godaddy? @Mattia Dinosaur

Comment: first of all，you should check whether you have enable the mysqlnd by phpinfo()

Comment: <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: It's giving me a lot of options. Please check it [here](http://abtsgh.com/). @Mattia Dinosaur

Comment: the first two line of page say"mysqlnd not enabled! 1-mysqlnd not enabled!"

Comment: yes. I checked whether `mysqli_fetch_all` and `get_result` is there or not. @Mattia Dinosaur

Comment: i do not know how you install the mysqlnd，may be you do not  install mysqlnd correctly.

Comment: finally,if the MySQL Native Driver (mysqlnd) driver is not available, and therefore using bind_result and fetch instead of get_result.

Comment: I didn't install it. I just enabled it from godaddy server. Anyway thanks for your time. I think I'll have to find an alternative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143556/discussion-between-ani-and-mattia-dinosaur).