# The mysqli num_rows returns 0 from mysqli OOP style

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am working on a login script and using `mysqli` OOP style. I write the `echo` script to check that it fetched the data or not. The result is the login data. But when I want to check the `num_rows`, it's return zero even if I use `$stmt->store_result`. I searched for many threads on this website and it doesn't work. `mysqli_num_rows` doesn't work too. Or I just missed some order of data storing?

Here is my code.

```
<?php
require_once "condb.php";

if (!isset($_POST['LOGIN']))
  {header("Location:index.php");}

else
{

  $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($cn,$_POST['username']);
  $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($cn,$_POST['password']);
  $hashed_password=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  $login = $cn->prepare("SELECT name,username,password,status
                       FROM login WHERE username=?");

  $login->bind_param("s", $username);
  $login->execute();
  $login->bind_result($name,$username,$password,$status);
  $login->store_result();
  $login->fetch();
  $count=$login->num_rows();

  echo $name."<br />".
  $username."<br />".
  $password."<br />".
  $status."<br />".$count;

/*Below here is if condition that I'll used when I finished solving this 
problem.*/

/*
if ($count > 0 )
{
   if(password_verify($password, $row['password']) && 
   $row['status']=="Admin")
   {
   echo "ok<br>You are Admin!";
   header("Location:admin/admin.php");
   $login->close();
   }elseif(password_verify($password, $row['password']) && 
    $row['status']=="Editor")
    {
      echo "ok<br>You are Editor!";
      $login->close();
    }elseif(password_verify($password, $row['password']) && 
    $row['status']=="Author")
    {
      echo "ok<br>You are Author!";
      $login->close();
     }
 else
 {
   echo "Username or password incorrect";
   $login->close();
   }
}
*/
}
?>
```

Comment: Your forgot the code

Comment: I've added already.

Comment: This comment is according to the latest code I've answered. `Sname` is the full name of the user and `$username` is what users use to login to the website. All of 4 variables I got are NOT NULL. I claim that it's true because I see the result from `var_dump();` and from `mysqli->execute();`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` anymore, if you are preparing the sql statements, because the preparation process already implies escaping. So, by using prepared statements you are on the safe side regarding MySQL injection.
- `num_rows` is not a method, but a property: `$count = $login->num_rows;`.
- You should use exception handling in order to be able to catch eventual errors.
- Use intention-revealing, pronounceable names for variables, properties and methods. And don't be afraid to provide long ones. See [Clean, high quality code guide](https://www.butterfly.com.au/blog/website-development/clean-high-quality-code-a-guide-on-how-to-become-a-better-programmer). Examples: `dbconnection.php` instead of `condb.php`, `$connection` instead of `$cn`, `$statement` instead of `$login`.

Maybe these answers can be of help for you too.

- [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182673/convert-php-pdo-code-to-mysqli-code/45185752#45185752) I recommend you to use option 1.
- [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223238/dynamic-data-for-navbar/45228937#45228937)

Good luck!

```
<?php

require_once 'condb.php';

/*
 * Enable internal report functions. This enables the exception handling, 
 * e.g. mysqli will not throw PHP warnings anymore, but mysqli exceptions 
 * (mysqli_sql_exception). They are catched in the try-catch block.
 * 
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR: Report errors from mysqli function calls.
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT: Throw a mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings. 
 * 
 * See:
 *      http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
 *      http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
 *      http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
 */
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

if (!isset($_POST['LOGIN'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
} else {
    try {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $sql = 'SELECT 
                name,
                username,
                password,
                status 
            FROM login 
            WHERE username = ?';

        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bind_param('s', $username);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->store_result();

        $count = $statement->num_rows;

        if ($count > 0) {
            $varsBound = $statement->bind_result($resultName, $resultUsername, $resultPassword, $resultStatus);

            $fetched = $statement->fetch();

            // For testing.
            var_dump($resultName);
            var_dump($resultUsername);
            var_dump($resultPassword);
            var_dump($resultStatus);

            if (password_verify($resultPassword, password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT))) {
                switch ($resultStatus) {
                    case 'Admin':
                        echo 'You are an Admin!';
                        // header("Location: admin/admin.php");
                        // exit();
                        break;

                    case 'Editor':
                        echo 'You are an Editor!';
                        //...
                        break;

                    case 'Author':
                        echo 'You are an Author!';
                        //...
                        break;

                    default:
                        //...
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Invalid password!';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid user name or no record found for the given user name!';
        }

        $statement->free_result();
        $statement->close();
        $connection->close();
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getCode() . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
}

/*
 * Disable internal report functions.
 * 
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF: Turns reporting off.
 * 
 * See:
 *      http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
 *      http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
 *      http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
 */
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF;
```

Comment: there is a room for improvement still. this code will benefit from getting rid of password_hash and while. the statement about bind_result is also a false one. not to metion that num-rows is not needed at all

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _this code will benefit from getting rid of password_hash..._

Comment: I don't know how to get rid of `while`, could you please show me/tell me how? And I would say, that using `num_rows` is better. Thanks.

Comment: If I use `num_rows`, I don't bind any results if no record found. This is an option I generally prefer. Let's suppose, that I only fetch a $resUsername, which can also be NULL. When not using num_rows, how would I check that NULL still not represents a valid record? As for your understanding about me: I always respect any opinion of other persons. That doesn't mean, that I agree with all opinions. In this case, I don't agree with yours. But you know, it's all about perception. So, maybe you have right. What is sure: I always have my reasons to bloat my code.

Comment: Another opinion with which I don't agree: I provided another order of the operations (`store_result` -> `bind_result` -> `fetch`), which I know is right. Unless I get a proof, that the order don't count, my answer is a legit one. I also provided two references to the code providing validations and exception handling, if needed. And, as long as @PaoPaoMC doesn't provide any feedback, you can't be certain that an error is raised. Bye bye.

Comment: Your problem is that you are making *groundless* statements and then asking other people to disprove them. The burden of  proving lays on one who makes a claim.

Comment: I remember that you valued some of my articles. Please consider another one: https://phpdelusions.net/socode You could benefit from #4

Comment: You choosed to disaprove something that I know for certain. That's why I'm asking for a proof. In the moment you claimed that it should not be taken as a certain situation, I specified this possibility in my answer. But, until you can proove I'm wrong, I stick with my assertion and answer. Trust me, I searched for a proof, but I didn't find one! All over the web the ops order is as I specified in my answer. That's why I'm asking you. You find this not right? Then, I'm sorry that my answer was downvoted by you, but I also respect your personal oppinion. Thanks for your comments, anyway.

Comment: Hello everyone , sorry for slowly responed for your solution. I've changed the order of the operation to `store_result -> bind_result -> fetch` then the `num_rows` immediately changed to 1. So, your first solution is OK. I changed only `elseif` part to `switch` and keep some part originally. Finally , the conclusion is just the first operation helps me the main problem and `if` and `switch` don't make any problems for me. Thank you for responds and answers.

Comment: I've bringed some code on my own answer. @YourCommonSense

Comment: @PaoPaoMC I'm glad that it worked for you. Good luck. P.S: Please note that also the solution of YourCommonSense is a very good and legit one.

Comment: @aendeerei I would use his solution to work out for results. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is simple. If (given that `store_result()` is called), `num_rows` returns 0, it means that your query found no rows. It's really simple. No need to look for some other code or blame a database. No rows to fetch? Then there is no such data in the database. Therefore, to make your query return something you need to **make sure** that `$_POST['username']` contains a value that exists in the database.

Moreover, I must tell you that this function/variable is the most useless part of mysqli (or any other database API). Any time you need it and it's available, it can be substituted with something else that you already have. In your case you can check the result of `fetch()` instead, which will serve for this purpose perfectly.

Having said that, I have a feeling that even with a query everything is all right and your problem is from variables you are using. You are using a non-existent $row variable which obviously will return nothing. Have you swithched the proper error reporting in PHP, it would have told you that already. So in any case just remember to handle errors properly, you can refer to my article, [PHP error reporting basics](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) for that.

So, in the end your code should be like this:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['LOGIN'])){
    header("Location:index.php");
    exit;
}
require_once "condb.php";

$sql = "SELECT name,username,password,status FROM login WHERE username=?";
$stmt = $cn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
$stmt->bind_result($name,$username,$password,$status);
$stmt->execute();

if ($login->fetch() and password_verify($_POST['password'], $password) {
    if ($status=="Admin")
    {
        header("Location:admin/admin.php");
        exit();
    }
    echo "ok<br>You are $status!";
} else {
   echo "Username or password incorrect";
}
```

As you can see, there were some other useless functions used in your code which I removed as well. You see, PHP code could be compact and tidy if you make it to do only what it have to do.

Comment: Regarding your first phrase: not really. In your code, e.g. without `store_result()`, `num_rows` would show `0`, even though the binded values for the record are valid db values.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote something that applied from your answers like this below.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once "condb.php";

if (!isset($_POST['LOGIN']))
{header("Location:index.php");}

else
{

  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $receivedpassword=$_POST['password'];
  $hashed_password=password_hash($receivedpassword,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  $login = $cn->prepare("SELECT name,username,password,status
                         FROM login 
                         WHERE username=?");

  $login->bind_param("s", $username);
  $login->execute();
  $login->store_result();
  $login->bind_result($name,$getusername,$getpassword,$status);
  $login->fetch();
  $count=$login->num_rows;

  echo $name."<br />".$getusername."<br />".$getpassword."<br />".
  $status."<br />".$count."<br />";
  var_dump($name);echo "<br />";
  var_dump($getusername);echo "<br />";
  var_dump($getpassword);echo "<br />";
  var_dump($status);echo "<br />";
  var_dump($count);echo "<br />";
  // start checking a row

  if($count > 0)
  { // start of username check

    echo 'You are going good of your username.'."<br />";

    if(password_verify($receivedpassword, $getpassword))
    { // start of pw check

      echo 'Your password is going good!'."<br />";

      //start to check permission
      switch ($status)
      {// start of switch
        case 'Admin':
          echo 'You are admin.';
          break;
        case 'Editor':
          echo 'You are editor.';
          break;
        case 'Author':
         echo 'You are author.';
         break;
        case 'User':
          echo 'You are user.';
          break;
        default:
          echo 'NO PERMISSION FOUND.';
          break;
      }// end of switch

    } // end of pw check

    // else from pw verify
    else
    { // check of incorrect password
      echo 'Your password isn\'t going good.';
    } // end of incorrect password check

  } // end of username check

  // else from $count > 0
  else
  {// No username found condition check

    echo 'Your username isn\'t going good.';

  } // end of no username found

}//end of everything

?>
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense What you call superstitions and mistakes - btw: which mistakes? - I call experience. I really wished, you would be more flexible and opened to other's oppinions and perspectives. Because I like your overall advices, solutions, tutorials, etc, it would be great though, to hear from you again.

Comment: Try not to use so many comments in your code, because they can be confusing. Especially the ones at the end of statements.