# num_rows alternative for webspace without MySQLnd

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqlnd

It seems the company I host my webserver with doesn't have MySQLnd installed (or at least not on my server). This means that in php I can not use `$stmt->get_result()`, which means I can not use `$result->num_rows()`. I instead have to use `$stmt->bind_result()` and `$stmt->fetch()`. Is there an alternative for people in my situation to easily get the number of rows without looping through with `fetch()`?

Also, same problem with `$result->num_rows_affected()`.

Comment: I'm confused, why can you not use `$stmt->get_result()`, it's not available? Is MySQLi or other libraries available?

Comment: @Twisty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result

Comment: Gotcha. If I recall, there is a way to get the number from prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an alternative. The best I could do was make a method that loops through the rows and returns the count:

```
function rowCount($stmt) {
    $count = 0;
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $count++;
    }
    $stmt->data_seek(0); //reset the stmt to the first row
    return $count;
}
```

Note this does not solve the rows_affected problem.