# get the json data by adding the ID from the first query to the other query

Tags: php, mysql, json

There are 2 tables.
I am using do while in the second table with satinID from the first table.
how do I do this as a single json data?

Table 1

```
<? Php
mysql_select_db ($database_intranet_connections, $ intranet_connections);
$query_mus = "SELECT
zey_satinalma.satinID,
zey_satinalma.mik,
zey_satinalma.fiyat,
zey_satinalma.alimtarih,
   FROM
zey_satinalma
WHERE
zey_satinalma.yilid = 2 AND
zey_satinalma.islendi <> 1
";
$ mus = mysql_query ($ query_mus, $ intranet_connections) or die (mysql_error ());
$ row_mus = mysql_fetch_assoc ($mus);

?>
```

Table 2

```
 <? php do {

$ colname = $ row_mus ['satinID'];
$ colname_columns = "-1";
if (isset ($ colname)) {
  $ colname_columns = $colname;
}
mysql_select_db ($database_intranet_connections, $ intranet_connections);
$query_kalanmikt $ = sprintf ( "SELECT zeytin_depo.zeytinID, zeytin_depo.kuyuID,  FROM zeytin_depo  WHERE kuyuID! = 8000 AND zeytin_depo.satinID =(%s)", GetSQLValueString ($colname_columns ," int "));
```

bla bla 
    ?>

[screen image as it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEBxw.png)

Comment: Show us the code as a whole (plus, the "while" part is missing), then the `GetSQLValueString` function, then explain us what you mean by "_how do I do this as a single json data?_", e.g. what you want exactly. And are you sure you want to use `mysql_` functions? Because mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I made a [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) solution (OOP style), because the [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.requirements.php) extension (the one you are using) is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Though, I strongly recommend you to begin using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.
- You can/should use one sql statement.
- You should [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) the sql statements in order to avoid SQL injection.
- Other resources: [How to use mysqli properly](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli), [PHP Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

Good luck.

```
<?php

// Db configs.
define('HOST', '...');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', '...');
define('USERNAME', '...');
define('PASSWORD', '...');

// Error reporting.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // Set it to 0 on a live server!

/**
 * Enable internal report functions. This enables the exception handling, 
 * e.g. mysqli will not throw PHP warnings anymore, but mysqli exceptions 
 * (mysqli_sql_exception). They are catched in the try-catch block.
 * 
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR: Report errors from mysqli function calls.
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT: Throw a mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings. 
 * 
 * See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
 * See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
 * See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
 */
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

/**
 * Create a new db connection.
 * 
 * @see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php
 */
$connection = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);

/*
 * The SQL statement to be prepared. Notice the so-called markers, 
 * e.g. the "?" signs. Later, when using bind_param(), they will 
 * be replaced with the corresponding values.
 * 
 * SQL statement explanation: Get all records (e.g. values for the 
 * given column names) from zeytin_depo, together with the 
 * corresponding details (e.g. field values) from zey_satinalma, 
 * filtered by the yilid, islendi and kuyuID values.
 * 
 * See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
 */
$sql = "SELECT 
            zd.zeytinID,
            zd.kuyuID,
            zs.satinID,
            zs.mik,
            zs.fiyat,
            zs.alimtarih,
        FROM zeytin_depo AS zd 
        LEFT JOIN zey_satinalma AS zs ON zs.satinID = zd.satinID 
        WHERE 
            zs.yilid = ? 
            AND zs.islendi <> ?
            AND zd.kuyuID != ?";

/*
 * Prepare the SQL statement for execution.
 * 
 * See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
 */
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

/*
 * Bind variables for the parameter markers (?) in the 
 * SQL statement that was passed to prepare(). The first 
 * argument of bind_param() is a string that contains one 
 * or more characters which specify the types for the 
 * corresponding bind variables.
 * 
 * See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
 */
$yilid = 2;
$islendi = 1;
$kuyuID = 8000;

$statement->bind_param('iii', $yilid, $islendi, $kuyuID);

/*
 * Execute the prepared SQL statement.
 * When executed, any parameter markers which exist ("?") will 
 * automatically be replaced with the appropriate data of the
 * binded variables.
 * 
 * See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
 */
$executed = $statement->execute();

/*
 * Get the result set from the prepared statement.
 * 
 * NOTA BENE:
 * Available only with mysqlnd ("MySQL Native Driver"). If this 
 * is not installed, then uncomment "extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll" in 
 * PHP config file (php.ini) and restart web server (I assume Apache) and 
 * mysql service. Or use the following functions instead:
 * mysqli_stmt::store_result() + mysqli_stmt::bind_result() + mysqli_stmt::fetch().
 * 
 * See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php
 * See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result
 */
$result = $statement->get_result();

/*
 * Get the number of rows in the result.
 * 
 * See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php
 */
$numberOfRows = $result->num_rows;

/*
 * Fetch data and save it into an array.
 * 
 * See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
 */
$fetchedData = array();
if ($numberOfRows > 0) {
    // Fetch all rows at once.
    $fetchedData = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    // ...or fetch one row at a time.
    // while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //     $fetchedData[] = $row;
    // }
}

/*
 * Free the memory associated with the result. You should 
 * always free your result when it is not needed anymore.
 * 
 * See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php
 */
$result->close();

/*
 * Close the prepared statement. It also deallocates the statement handle.
 * If the statement has pending or unread results, it cancels them 
 * so that the next query can be executed.
 * 
 * See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php
 */
$statementClosed = $statement->close();

// Just for testing: display fetched data as array.
echo '<pre>' . print_r($fetchedData, TRUE) . '</pre>';

/*
 * Just for testing: how to loop through the 
 * fetched data list and to use the values.
 */
foreach ($fetchedData as $key => $row) {
    echo 'Row ' . ($key + 1) . ': ';

    echo 'zeytinID is ' . $row['zeytinID'] . ', ';
    echo 'kuyuID is ' . $row['kuyuID'] . ', ';
    echo 'satinID is ' . $row['satinID'] . ', ';
    echo 'mik is ' . $row['mik'] . ', ';
    echo 'fiyat is ' . $row['fiyat'] . ', ';
    echo 'alimtarih is ' . $row['alimtarih'] . ', ';

    echo '<br/><br/>';
}

// Print json-encoded data.
echo json_encode($fetchedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
I create  view for second query. I made a single query with left join.
the result code is as successful as the.
Thank you for your interest

```
while($data= mysql_fetch_assoc($sat))
{
    //$dataarray["data"][]=array_map('utf8_encode',$data);
    $dataarray["data"][]=$data;

    }
    echo json_encode($dataarray,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```