# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result()

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm dealing with a fatal error, and I see a lot of solutions for it everywhere but I can't seem to find the right solution that fits in my code...

so this is the code where it goes wrong:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($server, $gebruiker, $wachtwoord, $database);

if($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Kon geen verbinding maken. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM producten WHERE naam LIKE ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);

        $param_term = '%' . $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';

        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "<p><a href=toevoegen.php?id=" . $row['id'] . " style=\"text-decoration: none\">" . $row["naam"] . "</a></p>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<p>Geen producten gevonden</p>";
            }

        } else {
            echo "ERROR: Kon $sql niet uitvoeren. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

this is the part that messes it all up:

```
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
```

Who can help me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result ?

Comment: Completely different codes I can't out that solution in my codes... I wish someone could help

Comment: What do you mean? You can't enable the mysqlnd driver?

Comment: How do I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, the solution:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $gebruiker, $wachtwoord, $database); //Connection to my database
    $query = "SELECT id, naam FROM producten WHERE naam LIKE ?";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $term = "%".$_REQUEST['term']."%";
    $statement->bind_param("s", $term);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    if($statement->num_rows() == 0) {
        echo "<p>Geen producten gevonden ".$_REQUEST['term']."</p>";
        $statement->close();
        $conn->close();
    } else {
        $statement->bind_result($id,$naam);
        while ($statement->fetch()) {
            echo "<p><a href=toevoegen.php?id=" . $id ." style=\"text-decoration: none\">" . $naam . "</a></p>";
        };
        $statement->close();
        $conn->close();
    };};
```

Comment: Can you please tell what is your PHP version and OS?

Comment: honestly i have no idea. i got my site from a webhost company. the old code used to work on usbwebserver.

Comment: well, you can always create a new php file contains `<?php phpinfo();` and it will tell you a lot about your PHP, but nevermind