# Fetch first image from foreign key table Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Reference: [Fetch first image from foreign key table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55712498/fetch-first-image-from-foreign-key-table) but this time in Laravel.

I started playing with Laravel and I want to take first image from every post and show these in my blade.

```
$secondpost = DB::table('posts')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->skip(1)
        ->take(8)
        ->get();

foreach ($secondpost as $spost)
$secondph = DB::table('post_images')
        ->select('filename')
        ->where('post_id', $spost->id)
        ->limit(1)
        ->get()
        ->pluck('filename');

return view ('pages.index', compact('firstp', 'fph', 'secondpost', 'secondph'));
```

```
<div class="row">
 @foreach ($secondpost as $secondp)
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 post-ab">
  <div class="row">
   @foreach ($secondph as $sph);
    <img src="{{url($sph)}}" class="imgpost" alt="">
   @endforeach
    <div class="bottomleft">
      <p class="ab-desc">{{$secondp->marca}} {{$secondp->model}}</p>
      <p class="ab-desc">{{$secondp->pret}} Eur</p>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 @endforeach
</div>
```

This code load only one image for every img src. Post_id is foreign key for posts table id.

Comment: What do you mean by "first image"? The first image linked to the post? You could try to sort images descending by "created_at" column and after that select only the first result.

Comment: in your code, value of $secondph continuously changing in each loop. you only get the value from last iteration of loop. you should store value from each loop into an array and pass that array into blade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you need to confirm.

1. You have created models for the table like `Post` for `posts` table and `PostImages` for `post_images` table. If not, follow the documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent
2. You have created the `hasMany` relationship in your `post` model with `post_images`. Like:

#### In `Post` model.

```
/**
* Get the images for the post.
*/
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\PostImage');
}
```

3. Then change in your controller to use early loading, Like:

```
$secondpost = \App\Post::with("images")
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->skip(1)
        ->take(8)
        ->get();
```

And now the view looks like:

```
<div class="row">
 @foreach ($secondpost as $secondp)
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 post-ab">
  <div class="row">
    @php
        $image = $secondp->images->first();
    @endphp
    <img src="{{url($image->filename)}}" class="imgpost" alt="">
    <div class="bottomleft">
      <p class="ab-desc">{{$secondp->marca}} {{$secondp->model}}</p>
      <p class="ab-desc">{{$secondp->pret}} Eur</p>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 @endforeach
</div>
```

**Solution: 2**

You can create another relationship with `hasOne` to get a single image like:

```
// In your Post model.

/**
* Get the default image for post.
*/
public function default_image()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\PostImage')->orderBy("id");
}
```

Make change in controller to use `->with("default_image")`.

And in view you can just use like:

```
    $secondp->default_image->filename
```

Comment: Thank you for reply!
I changed and now "->with("images")" gives me the error : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with() . I googled it but without result to understand.

Comment: Use `\App\Post` instead of `Db::table('posts`)` updated in solution. Make sure your models resides in `App` directory or change the path accordingly.

Comment: @VasiliuRobert does this help?

Comment: Sure!!!
I have also encountered some problems with column names but i solved them.
Thank you very much!!!