# how to put products in loop to show all product

Tags: php, mysql

This my product list file in php which i try to show list of all products with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/48837052/12033292. 
My category table name is category and product table name is products. 
I get category name from another page and show all products in this page

> Product list
>   I want to show all products but in output i see only one product in screen.

```
<?php
include('config.php');
// Upload configs.
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads');
define('UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE', 10485760); // 10MB.
//@changed_2018-02-17_14.28
define('UPLOAD_ALLOWED_MIME_TYPES', 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif');
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'bakery');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', '');
define('CHARSET', 'utf8');
/*
 * Enable internal report functions. This enables the exception handling, 
 * e.g. mysqli will not throw PHP warnings anymore, but mysqli exceptions 
 * (mysqli_sql_exception).
 * 
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR: Report errors from mysqli function calls.
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT: Throw a mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings. 
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
 */
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
/*
 * Create a new db connection
 * @see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php
 */
$connection = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);

if (!isset($_GET['category']) || empty($_GET['category']) ) {
    $errors[] = 'You must select a category in order to see its details!';
} else {
    $categoryId = $_GET['category'];

    /*
     * Get the product details.
     */
    $sql = 'SELECT * 
            FROM products 
            WHERE category = ? ';

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

    $statement->bind_param('i', $categoryId);

    $statement->execute();

    /*
     * Get the result set from the prepared statement.
     * 
     * NOTA BENE:
     * Available only with mysqlnd ("MySQL Native Driver")! If this 
     * is not installed, then uncomment "extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll" in 
     * PHP config file (php.ini) and restart web server (I assume Apache) and 
     * mysql service. Or use the following functions instead:
     * mysqli_stmt::store_result + mysqli_stmt::bind_result + mysqli_stmt::fetch.
     * 
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php
     * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result
     */
    $result = $statement->get_result();

    /*
     * Fetch data (all at once) and save it into an array.
     * 
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php
     */
    $products = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    /*
     * Free the memory associated with the result. You should 
     * always free your result when it is not needed anymore.
     * 
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php
     */
    $result->close();

    $statement->close();

    if (!$products) {
        $errors[] = 'No product found.';
    } else {
        $product = $products[0];
        $productName = $product['title'];
        $productQuantity = $product['price'];
        $productDescription = $product['description'];
         $productSpecification = $product['specification'];
         $productcategory  = $product['category'];
         $productsubcategory = $product['subcategory'];

        /*
         * Get the images list for the provided product.
         */
        $sql = 'SELECT * 
                FROM products_images 
                WHERE product_id = ?';

        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

        $statement->bind_param('i', $categoryId);

        $statement->execute();

        $result = $statement->get_result();

        $images = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        $result->close();

        $statement->close();

        $connection->close();
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Product details</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                padding: 30px;
            }

            .product-details tr td {
                padding: 5px;
            }

            .product-details .label {
                font-weight: 700;
            }

            .product-images {
                margin-top: 30px;
            }

            .product-images tr td {
                padding: 10px;
                font-weight: 700;
                background-color: #eee;
            }

            .product-images .label {
                color: #fff;
                font-weight: 700;
                background-color: #8daf15;
            }

            .product-images img {
                max-width: 400px;
                display: inline-block;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="page-container">
            <h2>Product details</h2>

            <?php
            if (isset($errors)) {
                echo implode('<br/>', $errors);
                exit();
            }
            ?>

            <table class="product-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">Name</td>
                    <td class="label">Quantity</td>
                    <td class="label">Description</td>
                    <td class="label">Images</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td><?php echo $productName; ?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $productQuantity; ?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $productDescription; ?></td>
                <?php
                foreach ($images as $image) {
                    $imageId = $image['id'];
                    $imageFilename = $image['filename'];
                    ?>
                        <td>
                            <img src="admin_4/<?php echo $imageFilename; ?>" alt="" />
                        </td>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: This is]This is my output but i want to show my all products

Comment: You are not looping your products' result, and since you used `$products[0]`, that would really only get the first result, not the rest. You seemed to looped the images just fine, so also do it for the product list

Comment: what can i do now?

Comment: Like what you did in the images

Comment: multiple images related with product

Comment: @CarlBinalla what is code for loop in  **$products[0]**

Comment: `foreach ($products as $product) {`

Comment: @CarlBinalla not worked ' foreach ($products as $product) {$productName = $product['title'];$productQuantity = $product['price']; $productDescription = $product['description']; $productSpecification = $product['specification']; $productcategory = $product['category']; $productsubcategory = $product['subcategory'];' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see all your products you need to loop through all of the results you get from your query and echo each of the keys you need.

I didn't test this code but here an example of how it should work:

```
   <table class="product-details">
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Name</td>
        <td class="label">Quantity</td>
        <td class="label">Description</td>
        <td class="label">Images</td>

    </tr>
    <?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $product['title']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product['description']; ?></td>
        <?php foreach ($images as $image) {
            $imageId = $image['id'];
            $imageFilename = $image['filename']; ?>
            <td><img src="admin_4/<?php echo $imageFilename; ?>" alt="" /></td>
        <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>   
</table>
```