# How to select row using bind_param php mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

Normally i use this code for echo page rows. It's work good.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($db_mysqli, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$page = $row['page'];
echo $page;
```

.....

Now i use `bind_param` this code for echo page rows. But not work , how can i do ?

```
$stmt = $db_mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$page = $row['page'];
echo $page;
```

Comment: What's the error? Can you give us any more debug information?

Comment: you received $result but use $row

Comment: instead of `$page = $row['page'];` use `$page = $result['page'];`

Comment: Any errors shown on screen or in your php errors log?

Comment: not show anything sir.

Comment: Put these lines before your code: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Any errors shown now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Problem description:

The `mysqli_result` object returned by the method `get_result` looks something like this:

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 3
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 1
    [type] => 0
)
```

As you can see, this object exposes only some properties (number of fields, number of rows, etc) about the record set from which you need to reference your data. So, you can not directly reference field values from it.

### Solution:

In order to reach to the needed data you'll have to call one of the methods defined in the `mysqli_result` class (`fetch_all`, `fetch_array`, `fetch_assoc`, etc):

```
//...
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$page = $row['page'];
//...
```

with `$row` representing the fetched record and being an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 13
    [page] => 21
    ...
)
```

For more details read [The `mysqli_result` class](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).

### About error and exception handling:

Please note that a proper [error and exception handling](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php) system is essential in the developing process. [This article](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) describes the steps needed to activate it in an elegant and thoroughly manner.

### Extensive example:

For clarity, I prepared an extensive example with all components needed for accessing a database using the `mysqli` extension. It presents the situation of having to fetch one or more records from a list of users - saved in a db table named `users`. Each user is described by its `id`, `name` and `age`.

It's up to you to implement the error/exception handling system - as described in the above mentioned article.

**index.php:**

*Option 1) Fetching only one record:*

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';

// Assign the values used to replace the sql statement markers.
$id = 10;

/*
 * The SQL statement to be prepared. Notice the so-called markers, 
 * e.g. the "?" signs. They will be replaced later with the 
 * corresponding values when using mysqli_stmt::bind_param.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
 */
$sql = 'SELECT 
            id,
            name,
            age 
        FROM users 
        WHERE id = ?';

/*
 * Prepare the SQL statement for execution - ONLY ONCE.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
 */
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

/*
 * Bind variables for the parameter markers (?) in the 
 * SQL statement that was passed to prepare(). The first 
 * argument of bind_param() is a string that contains one 
 * or more characters which specify the types for the 
 * corresponding bind variables.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
 */
$statement->bind_param('i', $id);

/*
 * Execute the prepared SQL statement.
 * When executed any parameter markers which exist will 
 * automatically be replaced with the appropriate data.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
 */
$statement->execute();

/*
 * Get the result set from the prepared statement.
 * 
 * NOTA BENE:
 * Available only with mysqlnd ("MySQL Native Driver")! If this 
 * is not installed, then uncomment "extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll" in 
 * PHP config file (php.ini) and restart web server (I assume Apache) and 
 * mysql service. Or use the following functions instead:
 * mysqli_stmt::store_result + mysqli_stmt::bind_result + mysqli_stmt::fetch.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result
 */
$result = $statement->get_result();

/*
 * Fetch data and save it into an array:
 * 
 *  Array
 *  (
 *      [id] => 10
 *      [name] => Michael
 *      [age] => 18
 *  )
 * 
 * @link https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
 */
$user = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

/*
 * Free the memory associated with the result. You should 
 * always free your result when it is not needed anymore.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php
 */
$result->close();

/*
 * Close the prepared statement. It also deallocates the statement handle.
 * If the statement has pending or unread results, it cancels them 
 * so that the next query can be executed.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php
 */
$statement->close();

/*
 * Close the previously opened database connection.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php
 */
$connection->close();

// Reference the values of the fetched data.
echo 'User id is ' . $user['id'] . '<br/>';
echo 'User name is ' . $user['name'] . '<br/>';
echo 'User age is ' . $user['age'] . '<br/>';
```

*Option 2) Fetching multiple records:*

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';

$id1 = 10;
$id2 = 11;

$sql = 'SELECT 
            id,
            name,
            age 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            id = ? 
            OR id = ?';

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

$statement->bind_param('ii', $id1, $id2);

$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();

/*
 * Fetch data and save it into an array:
 * 
 *  Array
 *  (
 *      [0] => Array
 *          (
 *              [id] => 10
 *              [name] => Michael
 *              [age] => 18
 *          )
 *  
 *      [1] => Array
 *          (
 *              [id] => 11
 *              [name] => Harry
 *              [age] => 59
 *          )
 *  )
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php
 */
$users = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$result->close();
$statement->close();
$connection->close();

// Reference the values of the fetched data.
foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
    echo 'User id is ' . $user['id'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'User name is ' . $user['name'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'User age is ' . $user['age'] . '<br/>';

    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

**connection.php:**

```
<?php

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'tests');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', 'root');

/*
 * Error reporting.
 * 
 * Also, define an error handler, an exception handler and, eventually, 
 * a shutdown handler function to handle the raised errors and exceptions.
 * 
 * @link https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting Error reporting basics
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); /* SET IT TO 0 ON A LIVE SERVER! */

/*
 * Enable internal report functions. This enables the exception handling, 
 * e.g. mysqli will not throw PHP warnings anymore, but mysqli exceptions 
 * (mysqli_sql_exception).
 * 
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR: Report errors from mysqli function calls.
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT: Throw a mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings. 
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
 */
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// Create a new db connection.
$connection = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);

// Set the desired connection charset
$connection->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

**Test data:**

```
id  name    age
---------------
9   Julie   23
10  Michael 18
11  Harry   59
```

**Create table syntax:**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $page = $row['page'];
}

echo $page;
```

Comment: agreed with @Arin  OP is doing right.Check here:- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#example-1881

Comment: @Arin I didn't say he needed to. Usually it's good practice - if and when in the future there are more parameters and variables. Using integers is better.

Comment: And I don't think you _can_ change `?` to `:s`... As I know, you can do this only with PDO, not with mysqli.

Comment: @dakis Sorry, I think you're right. I only use PDO for my applications - read it too fast. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: No problem. It happened to me too ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I try to avoid binding params as it can give strange results if not managed correctly.

I prefer to bind value as it will copy the point in time variable value, rather than maintaining the memory position connection.

However, mysqli seems to only support simplistic non-named param binding :(

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

```
$stmt = $db_mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $page = $row['page'];
     echo $page;
}
```

I’m more a fan of PDO than mysqli, easier to use.

Comment: I don't think you can change `?` to `:id`... As I know, you can do this only with PDO, not with mysqli. And `bind_value` does not exist. I might be wrong?

Comment: Just stumbled on that caveat myself. I hope they deprecate mysqli like they did mysql functions. It’s more convoluted than mysql was.

Comment: My thoughts too :-) Though I understood that mysqli provide some good motivated services, not provided by PDO.

Comment: @dakis name one?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Unfortunately I can't mention one/them right now. I read about it somewhere, some months ago, but I can't remember where. I will try to re-find that - or other - source and I will give you my feedback.

Comment: @dakis don't trust everything you read on the Internet, there are too much clueless people writing thing they are not certain of. Don't write something you don't know for sure as well

Comment: @YourCommonSense I give my best to not trust everything. As I recall, though, the source was some official php/pdo/mysqli source.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks for the appreciation in your "edit" comment. One question, because you made me curious and, as always, surprised me - in a good way: Can you please tell me why you excluded the part with the integer type in the first _bind_param()_ parameter from my answer? I thought this would be an important thing of the method.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Wrong about the need of mysqli extension, or about the _bind_param_ parameter?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I see. Thank you.