# Error on Form submission with PHP, mySQL and XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, database, html, error-handling

I have verification code I wrote with help from a tutorial. The code looks correct to me, and the submit button on the form links to the right page, using the 'POST' method. However, on submitting the signup info, the browser opens a backend page, displaying some parts of the script. Obviously, it's not meant to do that, rather, it's to access the said page for verification and link back to the signup page with a success message embedded in the url.

Here is the signup.php page that contains the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Signup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signupstyle.css">
</head>

<body> 

    <div class="signup-wrapper">
        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
        <form class="signup-form" action="functions/signup.func.php" method="POST">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
                </li>

                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                </li>

                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                </li>

                <li>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                </li>

                <li>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                </li>

                <li>
                    <button>Sign Up</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>

    <footer>

    </footer>   
</body>
</html>
```

The page it is to post to is backend and here is the code for that:

```
<? php
if (isset($POST['submit'])) { //ensure that the submit button was pressed to 
access the page.
include_once 'dbc.func.php';

$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lname']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

//HANDLING ERRORS
//Checking for empty fields
if (empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($username) || empty($email) || ($password)) {
    header("Location: .../signup.php?signupfields=empty"); //if any of the above are empty, redirect to signup page.
    exit();
}else{
    //Checking for invalid input characters
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $fname) || (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $lname)) {
        header("Location: .../signup.php?signupfields=invalidchars"); //if any of the above are empty, redirect to signup page.
        exit();
    }else{
        //Checking the email validity
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            header("Location: .../signup.php?signupfields=invalidemail"); //if any of the above are empty, redirect to signup page.
            exit();
        }else{
            //Checking for username similarity
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'"; 
            $resulter = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $checkResulter = mysqli_num_rows($resulter);

            if ($checkResulter > 0) {
                header("Location: .../signup.php?signupfields=usernametaken"); //if any of the above are empty, redirect to signup page.
                exit();
            }else{
                //Hashing the inputted password 
                $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                //Inserting the inputted user details into the database 
                $inputer = "INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, username, email, password) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$username', '$email', '$hashedPassword');";
                mysqli_query($conn,$inputer);
                header("Location: .../signup.php?signupsuccess"); //redirect to signup page.
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}

}else{
header("Location: ../signup.php?badlogin"); //redirect users to the 
signup.php page.
exit();
}
```

It would seem everything is in order, but it throws the signup.func.php page with the following code displaying on the page:

```
0) { header("Location: .../signup.php?signupfields=usernametaken"); //if any of the above are empty, redirect to signup page. exit(); }else{ //Hashing the inputted password $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //Inserting the inputted user details into the database $inputer = "INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, username, email, password) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$username', '$email', '$hashedPassword');"; mysqli_query($conn,$inputer); header("Location: .../signup.php?signupsuccess"); //redirect to signup page. exit(); } } } } }else{ header("Location: ../signup.php?badlogin"); //redirect users to the signup.php page. exit(); }
```

Unsurprisingly, it's not meant to do that, and I'm fatigued with finding no errors in the code. Can anyone help me out?

EDIT:

After reading the articles provided, I used the error handler

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

And it gave me this when I ran the code again:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rizeapp\functions\dbc.func.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rizeapp\functions\dbc.func.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Rizeapp\functions\dbc.func.php(10): mysqli_connect('localhost, root...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Rizeapp\functions\signup.func.php(4): include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rizeapp\functions\dbc.func.php on line 10

If this is what I think it means, it's that the XAMPP server details are incorrect. I'll look into fixing that and see if the code will run.

EDIT 2: I literally shouted in joy when it worked. The second error thrown in EDIT 1 above was due to the most silly mistake known to me: I did this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("$dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, 
$dbName");
```

Instead of this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("$dbServername", "$dbUsername", "$dbPassword", 
"$dbName");
```

Thank you all for your swift replies that ultimately fixed the problem. Now, I can continue with the project full steam ahead. Cheers.

[erroneous page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTVXH.png)

Comment: The only way i cab see that happening is if you accidentally inserted a ? into the if ($checkResulter > 0) part.

Comment: @AndrewShmig Yup, it's not working. Well, it's working partially. daki's solution seemed to have pointed out all the syntax errors, but using Sublime Text doesn't really help with inline error detection for new programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found problems:**

- First code line is wrong: `<? php`. The php file presents then the code like a text file. Correct: `<?php`.
- Before the second `!preg_match...` in the `if` statement is a wrong character `(`. Correct: to be removed.
- In php code, when writing comment lines without starting with `//`, or outside `/* ... */`, an error occurres.
- Wrong: `$POST['submit']`. The correct global variable for the HTTP POST method is named `$_POST`. So, the correct code is: `$_POST['submit']`.
- If you define `<button>Sign Up</button>`, then you have to give it a name (like `<button name="submit">Sign Up</button>`) in order to be able to reference it by it with `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}`.
- Wrong: `.../abc/xyz.php`. Correct: `../abc/xyz.php`.
- Wrong: `if (... || empty($email) || ($password)) {...}`. Correct: `if (... || empty($email) || empty($password)) {...}`.

**Suggestions:**

- Put the php processing code in `signup.php`, instead of in `signup.func.php` and change it correspondingly. The form's *action* attribute will be `signup.php`, or `""` for *HTML5*, then. That way you are able to directly (e.g. on-site) display any message to the user and also to perform only a single redirect in the end, when the sign-up processing is successful (for example to a `login.php` page).
- Apply a good [error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) system, in order to see and correspondingly handle the errors and exceptions that the php engine might throw. For mysqli specifically: [here](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting). For PDO [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors).
- Start using the so called [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), in order to prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Read [this](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli) little, but effective article.
- Start using the object-oriented mysqli extension instead of the procedural one - each mysqli function have the php.net documentation presented in both forms. Even better: start using the [PDO extension](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead of mysqli. Here the (same as above) [tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).

---

**The alternative code (with object-oriented mysqli), as promised**

It includes my above suggestions. Run it as it is to test it. But change the table structure first (see title *Used table structure* below), change the db credentials in *connection.php* (see title *includes/connection.php* below) and create a filesystem structure as suggested by the titles of the code parts below.

To toggle from a *production* environment (when the errors are not shown on screen) to a *development* environment (when all raised errors are displayed on screen), just change the value of the constant *APP_ENV* (in *handlers.php*) from *'prod'* to *'dev'* and back (see title *includes/handlers.php*). And then, to test it, rename the table name "users" to another wrong name, for example. Or set the first of the two sql statements to `NULL`: `$sql = NULL;`.

#### signup.php

```
<?php
require 'includes/handlers.php';
require 'includes/connection.php';

// Signalize if a new account could be created, or not.
$accountCreated = FALSE;

/*
 * ====================================
 * Operations upon form submission.
 * ====================================
 */
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /*
     * ====================================
     * Read the posted values.
     * ====================================
     */
    $firstName = isset($_POST['firstName']) ? $_POST['firstName'] : '';
    $lastName = isset($_POST['lastName']) ? $_POST['lastName'] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

    /*
     * ====================================
     * Validate all posted values together.
     * ====================================
     */
    if (empty($firstName) && empty($lastName) && empty($email) && empty($username) && empty($password)) {
        $errors[] = 'All values are mandatory. Please provide them.';
    }

    /*
     * ====================================
     * Validate each value separately.
     * ====================================
     */
    if (!isset($errors)) {
        // Validate the first name.
        if (empty($firstName)) {
            $errors[] = 'Please provide a first name.';
        } elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]*$/', $firstName)) {
            $errors[] = 'The first name contains invalid characters.';
        } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

        // Validate the last name.
        if (empty($lastName)) {
            $errors[] = 'Please provide a last name.';
        } elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]*$/', $lastName)) {
            $errors[] = 'The last name contains invalid characters.';
        } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

        // Validate the email.
        if (empty($email)) {
            $errors[] = 'Please provide an email address.';
        } elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors[] = 'The email address is not in a valid format.';
        } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

        // Validate the username.
        if (empty($username)) {
            $errors[] = 'Please provide a username.';
        } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

        // Validate the password.
        if (empty($password)) {
            $errors[] = 'Please provide a password.';
        } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */
    }

    /*
     * ====================================
     * Check if user exists. Save if not.
     * ====================================
     */
    if (!isset($errors)) {
        /*
         * ====================================
         * Check if user already exists.
         * ====================================
         */

        /*
         * The SQL statement to be prepared. Notice the so-called markers,
         * e.g. the "?" signs. They will be replaced later with the
         * corresponding values when using mysqli_stmt::bind_param.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
         */
        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM users
                WHERE username = ?';

        /*
         * Prepare the SQL statement for execution - ONLY ONCE.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
         */
        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

        /*
         * Bind variables for the parameter markers (?) in the
         * SQL statement that was passed to prepare(). The first
         * argument of bind_param() is a string that contains one
         * or more characters which specify the types for the
         * corresponding bind variables.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
         */
        $statement->bind_param('s', $username);

        /*
         * Execute the prepared SQL statement.
         * When executed any parameter markers which exist will
         * automatically be replaced with the appropriate data.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
         */
        $statement->execute();

        /*
         * Transfer the result set resulted from executing the prepared statement.
         * E.g. store, e.g. buffer the result set into the (same) prepared statement.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php
         * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result
         */
        $statement->store_result();

        /*
         * Bind the result set columns to corresponding variables.
         * E.g. these variables will hold the column values after fetching.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php
         */
        $statement->bind_result($numberOfFoundUsers);

        /*
         * Fetch the results from the result set (of the prepared statement) into the bound variables.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php
         */
        $statement->fetch();

        /*
         * Free the stored result memory associated with the statement,
         * which was allocated by mysqli_stmt::store_result.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php
         */
        $statement->free_result();

        /*
         * Close the prepared statement. It also deallocates the statement handle.
         * If the statement has pending or unread results, it cancels them
         * so that the next query can be executed.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php
         */
        $statement->close();

        if ($numberOfFoundUsers > 0) {
            $errors[] = 'The given username already exists. Please choose another one.';
        } else {
            /*
             * ====================================
             * Save a new user account.
             * ====================================
             */
            // Create a password hash.
            $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

            $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (
                        first_name,
                        last_name,
                        email,
                        username,
                        password
                    ) VALUES (
                        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
                    )';

            $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bind_param('sssss', $firstName, $lastName, $email, $username, $passwordHash);
            $statement->execute();

            // Signalize that a new account was successfully created.
            $accountCreated = TRUE;

            // Reset all values so that they are not shown in the form anymore.
            $firstName = $lastName = $email = $username = $password = NULL;
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo - Sign Up </title>

        <!--<link href="assets/images/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/png" />-->

        <!-- CSS assets -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/css/app.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/css/signup.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- JS assets -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="page-container">

            <nav class="navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="signup.php" class="active">Sign Up</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h2 class="page-title">
                    Sign Up
                </h2>
                <div class="page-subtitle">
                    Hello. We are happy to see you here. Please fill in the form to register.
                </div>
            </header>

            <section class="page-content">

                <section class="form-container-outer">
                    <section class="form-container-inner">
                        <?php
                        if (isset($errors)) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="messages danger">
                                <?php echo implode('<br/>', $errors); ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        } elseif ($accountCreated) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="messages success">
                                You have successfully created your account.
                                <br/>Would you like to <a href="#">login</a> now?
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                        <form id="signup-form" action="" method="post">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="firstName">First Name <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="<?php echo isset($firstName) ? $firstName : ''; ?>" placeholder="First Name" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lastName">Last Name <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="<?php echo isset($lastName) ? $lastName : ''; ?>" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($email) ? $email : ''; ?>" placeholder="Email" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username">Username <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo isset($username) ? $username : ''; ?>" placeholder="Username" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Password <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="<?php echo isset($password) ? $password : ''; ?>" placeholder="Password" required>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" id="signupButton" name="submit" value="signup">
                                Create account
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </section>
                </section>

            </section>

            <footer class="footer">
                &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <a href="#" title="Demo">Demo</a>. All rights reserved.
            </footer>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### includes/connection.php

```
<?php

/*
 * This page contains the code for creating a mysqli connection instance.
 */

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'tests');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', 'root');

/*
 * Enable internal report functions. This enables the exception handling,
 * e.g. mysqli will not throw PHP warnings anymore, but mysqli exceptions
 * (mysqli_sql_exception).
 *
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR: Report errors from mysqli function calls.
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT: Throw a mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
 */
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

/*
 * Create a new db connection.
 *
 * @see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php
 */
$connection = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);
```

#### includes/handlers.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Include this page in all PHP pages of the application.
 *
 * This page contains:
 *  - The APP_ENV constant, used to decide in which environment this application runs.
 *  - The functions for handling all the errors, or exceptions, raised by the application.
 *  - The code for setting them as error/exception handlers.
 *  - The code deciding if the errors should be displayed on the screen. The errors
 *    display MUST be activated ONLY in the development stage of the application. When
 *    the website goes live, ALL ERRORS must be written in a/the log file and NO ERRORS
 *    should be displayed on screen, but only a general, user-friendly message, or a
 *    custom error page.
 */

/*
 * Decide in which environment this application runs. Possible values:
 *  - 'prod' (app in production, e.g. live). The errors are not displayed, but only logged.
 *  - 'dev' (app in development). The errors are displayed on screen and logged.
 *  - 'test' (app in tests). Same as 'dev'.
 *  - etc.
 */
define('APP_ENV', 'dev');

// Activate the errors/exceptions logging.
ini_set('log_errors', 1);

// Set the error reporting level: report all errors.
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Decide how to handle the errors/exceptions.
if (APP_ENV === 'prod') { // App in production, e.g. live.
    // DON'T display the errors/exceptions on the screen.
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);

    // Set the handler functions.
    set_error_handler('errorHandler');
    set_exception_handler('exceptionHandler');
} else { // App in development, tests, etc.
    // Display the errors/exceptions on the screen.
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
}

/**
 * Error handler:
 *  - Print a user-friendly message, or show a custom error page.
 *  - Log the error.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php set_error_handler.
 * @param int $errno
 * @param string $errstr
 * @param string $errfile
 * @param int $errline
 */
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    echo 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again, or contact us.';
    error_log('Error ' . $errno . ' - ' . $errstr . ' in file ' . $errfile . ' on line ' . $errline);
    exit();
}

/**
 * Exception handler:
 *  - Print a user-friendly message, or show a custom error page.
 *  - Log the error.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php set_exception_handler.
 * @param Exception $exception
 */
function exceptionHandler($exception) {
    echo 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again, or contact us.';
    error_log('Exception ' . $exception->getCode() . ' - ' . $exception->getMessage() . ' in file ' . $exception->getFile() . ' on line ' . $exception->getLine());
    exit();
}
```

#### assets/css/app.css

```
/***************************************/
/* Base settings */
/***************************************/

html {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* Font size: 100% = 16px (in almost all web browsers) */
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #000;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    background-color: #fff;
}

/*
    A font size of 1rem means 16px. E.g. 100% of the font size of the "html" tag, which is 16px.
    A font size of 0.9375rem means: 0.9375 * 16px = 15px.
    From this point on, for font sizes, work with "rem", or "em" units, not anymore with px.
    The "rem" units are always relative to the font size of the "html" tag (here 16px, because is set as 100%).
    The "em" units are always relative to the font size of the parent tag.
*/
body {
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    position: relative;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #DF9237;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #000;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 300;
}

/* A font size of 2.5rem means: 2.5 * 16px = 40px */
h2 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

/***************************************/
/* Fonts settings */
/***************************************/

html, body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif !important;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
.navbar-nav li a,
.page-title,
.page-subtitle {
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif !important;
}

/***************************************/
/* Layout settings */
/***************************************/

/* Page container */

/*
    The top-padding is the navbar's height (70px) + some additional pixels (30px).
    The bottom-padding is the footer's height (60px) + some additional pixels (30px).
*/
.page-container {
    /* Making relative position so, that we can absolute position the footer on the bottom */
    position: relative;
    padding: 100px 30px 90px 30px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* Navigation bar */

/*
    Navbar must have a fixed height. Example here: 70px (padding is included because of
    box-sizing: border-box in html). Then make the top-padding of the .page-container
    the same height (70px) + some additional pixels, in order to avoid overlapping!
*/
.navbar {
    height: 70px;
    padding: 22px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 60px;
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-nav li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
    padding: 7px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover {
    color: #DF9237;
}

.navbar-nav li a.active {
    color: #DF9237;
}

.navbar-nav li a.active:hover {
    color: #000;
}

/* Page header */

.page-header {
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.page-title {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #DF9237;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.page-subtitle {
    /*margin-top: 10px;*/
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.0625rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.page-content {

}

/* Messages */

.messages {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.success {
    color: #3c763d;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
}

.danger {
    color: #a94442;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
    background-color: #f2dede;
}

.warning {
    color: #8a6d3b;
    border-color: #faebcc;
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
}

/* Mandatory fields in forms */

.mandatory {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    color: #DF9237;
}

/* Footer */

/*
    Footer must have a fixed height. Example here: 60px (padding is included because of
    box-sizing: border-box in html). Then make the bottom-padding of the .page-container
    the same height (60px) + some additional pixels, in order to avoid overlapping!
*/
.footer {
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

#### assets/css/signup.css

```
/* Form */

.form-container-outer {
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.form-container-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.messages {
    text-align: left;
}

.messages a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.messages.success {
    text-align: center;
}

#signup-form {
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-group label {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100px;
}

input {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
}

button {
    padding: 7px 10px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #449d44;
}
```

#### Used table structure

Since you are using the proper hashing function (`password_hash`), let the `password` column's length be at least 255 characters long.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I made a lot of errors and I'm glad you pointed them out. I read all the articles and will re-read them indepth when I have the time. The corrected code ran, but not without problems, I'm afraid. When the form is filled and submitted, the result is the second 'if' statement for catching empty fields. If I negate the conditionals to !empty(...), it takes me to the fourth 'if' statement for catching errors on email validity. I'm completely new to PHP, and I hope you can help me a bit more on this. Thanks for your painstaking reply to my first question, once again.

Comment: @VyzEjstu You are welcome. Yes, I just saw the connection errors you faced and I am glad that you could discover and resolve the problem. The most important part is, that, now, you can see the errors and act accordingly... In the development stage - like yours, now, is completely ok to see specific errors on screen. But be aware that, when your website goes live, no one - not even you - must see any specific errors on screen. All errors will be saved into a log file instead, and the users will receive just a general, user-friendly error message, or page, on the screen.

Comment: @VyzEjstu That is why is very important that you read at least the error handling tutorials that I gave you, before anything else... That said, I will try until tomorrow evening to write a complete solution for you, so that you see, how you can approach the workflow in another, simpler manner (with my naming and coding conventions).

Comment: Thank you very much, @dakis. I'll be sure to read the articles today. Thanks, once again.

Comment: @VyzEjstu As promised, I reedited my answer with the new code (using object-oriented mysqli). A lot of comments in the pages, so... have fun :-) I also prepared an identical answer, but using PDO. Also with a lot of comments. You decide if you want to use PDO from now on. I strongly suggest you to do that as soon as possible. So, just tell me and I'll replace the codes of `includes/connection.php` and `signup.php` in my answer with the PDO versions... Note that I changed the db table structure, too... Maybe you'll find my naming and coding conventions better for you... Until then. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your Initial `$POST['submit']` should be **`$_POST['submit']`**

Also you'll need to add a name attribute to the submit button in your markup.

Your `("Location: .../..")` Should be `("Location: ../..")`.

This are my observation, i'm sorry i couldn't run the code to give you the working code.

Thanks.