# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Tags: php, mysql, web, pdo

Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

How to use it right?

```
    public static function login($benutzername, $passwort){
        $result = Connection::getInstance()->db;
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE benutzername = ? AND passwort = ?';
        $stmt = $result->prepare($sql);
        $passwort = md5($passwort);
```

maybe use mysqli-stmt.bind-result ?

```
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $benutzername, $passwort);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

or mysqli_stmt_fetch?

```
        if ($result->num_rows != '0') {}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you tagged as pdo but using mysqli_, why? and what is the connection, pdo or mysqli_?

Comment: you're using md5 to store passwords with? in this day and age? that's over 30 years ago and it's too old and broken; use password_hash().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result

Comment: `Available only with mysqlnd.` Make sure you have mysqlnd installed.

Comment: and I added another (possible) duplicate to the one that was chosen by others.

Comment: wee bit of a pro side note: when people type a comment to you, it would help everyone to be on the same page and respond. How do you like one-way conversations? Pretty annoying huh? Yeah; I know what you mean, I get those all the time when I talk to a wall.

Comment: wanna use pdo, should rename this. mysqlnd is available. i'll try your notices and post the new code below.