# What's this PDO Code in mysqli?

Tags: php, post, pdo

### I Need this Code converted to a normal mysqli Code, but I am not able to do that.

All my other PHP Code isn't in PDO and I want every Code in the same Kind.
Hopefully anyone of you can help me :)

```
  <?php

 include 'config.inc.php';
 
 // Check whether username or password is set from android  
 if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
 {
      // Innitialize Variable
      $result='';
    $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
    
      
      // Query database for row exist or not
      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE  username = :username AND password = :password';
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    

    
      $stmt->execute();
      if($stmt->rowCount())
      {
         $result="true";    
      }  
      elseif(!$stmt->rowCount())
      {
            $result="false";
      }
      
      // send result back to android
      echo $result;
}

?>
```

Comment: So are you looking for our hourly rates? Don't store plain text passwords.

Comment: You should choose to change all mysqli codes to pdo, not otherwise. Here is [Why 1](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison) and [Why 2](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, I recommend using the PDO extension. But if you choose to use mysqli instead, then use the object-oriented mysqli instead of the procedural one. On php.net each mysqli function is presented in both ways.

The password should be strongly encrypted. My recommendation: the [password_hash](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function - either with the `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` option (a constant defining the Blowfish hashing algorithm), or with the `PASSWORD_ARGON2I` option (constant defining the Argon2 hashing algorithm and introduced as of PHP 7.2.0). So, you should first save new user credentials in the form of a password hash (a string of minimum 60 aleatory characters) - in the `users` table. With a code similar to this one:

**signup.php:**

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// Create a hash from a posted password.
$passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)';

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param('ss', $username, $passwordHash);
$statement->execute();

//...
```

For a clear view regarding your question here's an extended example of a login page - using my own naming and coding conventions. How you decide to adapt it, e.g. to process the results, is up to your logical scheme and system - I'm not familiar with Android. The code contains a server-side credentials validation part too. For proper error reporting see [this article](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting). Don't forget to change the db credentials.

**connection.php:**

```
<?php

/*
 * This page contains the code for creating a mysqli connection instance.
 */

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'tests');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', 'root');

/*
 * Enable internal report functions. This enables the exception handling,
 * e.g. mysqli will not throw PHP warnings anymore, but mysqli exceptions
 * (mysqli_sql_exception).
 *
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR: Report errors from mysqli function calls.
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT: Throw a mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
 */
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

/*
 * Create a new db connection.
 *
 * @see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php
 */
$connection = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);
```

**login.php:**

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';

/*
 * ================================
 * Operations upon form submission.
 * ================================
 */
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /*
     * =======================
     * Read the posted values.
     * =======================
     */
    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

    /*
     * ===========================
     * Validate the posted values.
     * ===========================
     */
    // Validate the username.
    if (empty($username)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide a username.';
    } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

    // Validate the password.
    if (empty($password)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide a password.';
    } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

    /*
     * ======================
     * Check the credentials.
     * ======================
     */
    if (!isset($errors)) { // No errors yet.
        /*
         * The SQL statement to be prepared. Notice the so-called markers,
         * e.g. the "?" signs. They will be replaced later with the
         * corresponding values when using mysqli_stmt::bind_param.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
         */
        $sql = 'SELECT username, password
                FROM users
                WHERE username = ?
                LIMIT 1';

        /*
         * Prepare the SQL statement for execution.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
         */
        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

        /*
         * Bind variables for the parameter markers (?) in the
         * SQL statement that was passed to prepare(). The first
         * argument of bind_param() is a string that contains one
         * or more characters which specify the types for the
         * corresponding bind variables.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
         */
        $statement->bind_param('s', $username);

        /*
         * Execute the prepared SQL statement.
         * When executed any parameter markers which exist will
         * automatically be replaced with the appropriate data.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
         */
        $statement->execute();

        /*
         * Get the result set from the prepared statement.
         *
         * NOTA BENE:
         * Available only with mysqlnd ("MySQL Native Driver")! If this
         * is not installed, then uncomment "extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll" in
         * PHP config file (php.ini) and restart web server (I assume Apache) and
         * mysql service. Or use the following functions instead:
         * mysqli_stmt::store_result + mysqli_stmt::bind_result + mysqli_stmt::fetch.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php
         * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result
         */
        $result = $statement->get_result();

        /*
         * Fetch the credentials into an associative array.
         * If no record is found, the operation returns NULL.
         */
        $credentials = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        if (isset($credentials) && $credentials) { // Record found.
            $fetchedUsername = $credentials['username'];
            $fetchedPasswordHash = $credentials['password'];

            /*
             * Compare the posted username with the one saved in db and the posted
             * password with the password hash saved in db using password_hash.
             *
             * @link https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
             * @link https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
             */
            if (
                    $username === $fetchedUsername &&
                    password_verify($password, $fetchedPasswordHash)
            ) {
                header('Location: welcome.html');
                exit();
            } else {
                $errors[] = 'Invalid credentials. Please try again.';
            }
        } else {
            $errors[] = 'No credentials found for the given user.';
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo - Login</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#username').focus();
            });

            function validateForm() {
                return true;
            }
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                padding: 30px;
            }

            label {
                display: block;
                font-weight: 400;
            }

            input[type="text"],
            input[type="password"] {
                display: block;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            button {
                display: block;
                padding: 7px 10px;
                background-color: #8daf15;
                color: #fff;
                border: none;
            }

            .messages {
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            .messages .error {
                color: #c00;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="messages">
            <?php
            if (isset($errors)) {
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="error">
                        <?php echo $error; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-login">
            <form name="credentials" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo isset($username) ? $username : ''; ?>">

                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="<?php echo isset($password) ? $password : ''; ?>">

                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**The table structure used for testing:**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**The data used for testing:**

This data would be saved by running the `signup.php` code. Each password hash here (e.g. each value of the `password` column) is the encrypted representation of the corresponding value of the `username` column. For example, the first hash represents the string (e.g. the password) "demo1".

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`)
VALUES
    (1, 'demo1', '$2y$10$ZzULeTfsMwBj6DwpsfzxPu0irOrkL.l7rkimPkpcojL4RAMLwEZkW'),
    (2, 'demo2', '$2y$10$bpLOz4ur4wdVs4RN9ZatGekmynMhgOAdkwBchRLAf2t8hwc9Kkh7K');
```

Comment: For the users who will maybe decide to downvote my question: Please let me know the motive of your downvote, so that I can change my answer correspondingly. I am open to all your suggestions or critiques. Thanks.