# PHP crashing when try to get_results

Tags: php, mysql

sorry to ask a basic question. I am new in PHP programming. I have the below code which is crashing when it gets the get_result row.
I already tested in my local computer iis installation and works fine. But when I put it to work in the web hosting it crashes. Would you please take a look?
I appreciate your support.

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pwd";
    $dbname = "db";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // check conn
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from catusuarios where userid = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST["userid"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $user = $result->fetch_object();
    $conn->close();
```

Comment: Can you post the error message you're seeing?

Comment: Can you post the errors that get logged when it "crashes"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result

Comment: Thanks guys! Specially Bill Karwin, the article suggested was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

For those having the same issue, the API Extensions under mysqlnd was empty. I went into cPanel >> Select PHP version, and selected nd_mysqli.