# I found this error undefined mysqli_stmt::get_result() error in my site

Tags: php, mysqli, bootstrap-4, prepared-statement

I currently hosted my side on linux server on godaddy and I got this error "undefined mysqli_stmt::get_result()".

My server has already installed mysqlnd and get_result is also enabled.
This is my code where I got the error:

```
<?php 
require_once('inc/db.php');
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
require_once 'inc/functions.php';
ob_start();
session_start();
  //site settings
   $setting_query = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_settings");  
   $setting_query->execute();
   $setting_result = $setting_query->get_result(); //Here, I got the error
   $settings = $setting_result->num_rows;
   if($settings>0){
       $site_data = $setting_result->fetch_assoc();
       $site_name = $site_data['site_name'];
   } ?>
```

Please help me..

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined method mysqli\_stmt::get\_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result)