# Unable to fetch multiple row data from mysql using prepared object statements

Tags: php, prepared-statement, mysqli

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username=? OR email = ?");
$sql->bind_param('ss', $uname, $email);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if ($row['username'] == $uname) {
    echo "Username not availabe try different";
} elseif ($row['email'] == $email) {
    echo "email is already taken diiferent";
} else {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, pass, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $pass, $created);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Registrated sucessfully. Login Now!";
    } else {
        echo "Something went wrong. Please try again";
    }
}
```

This code is not running. I don't know why. 
If I'm fetching a single row then it is working but for multiple rows it is not working.

Here I want to validate whether a username and email already exists in the db using prepared statements.

Comment: Try putting (!$stmt) { mysqli_error($conn);   In places to see where code breaks or any error messages. Are you getting to something wrong part?

Comment: On inspecting in chrome  it is showing this error: jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST http://localhost//action.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ login.php:208
dispatch @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
y.handle @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2

Comment: I know this is not the error of ajax or jquery because I've  debugged it everything is fine like data is coming from the form and also it working in fetching a single row but not working for multiple rows. Here I want to validate whether a username and email is already exits or not in the db using prepared statements. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finally, after a 3-4 hours of exercise, I resolve this issue with help of this stack overflow article:[call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result)**

If anyone have same issue because of native driver refer to this article.
This is the solution which works for me is given below: First define this function

```
function fetchAssocStatement($stmt)
{
    if($stmt->num_rows>0)
    {
        $result = array();
        $md = $stmt->result_metadata();
        $params = array();
        while($field = $md->fetch_field()) {
            $params[] = &$result[$field->name];
        }
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
        if($stmt->fetch())
            return $result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

as you can see it creates an array and fetches it with the row data, since it uses `$stmt->fetch()` internally, you can call it just as you would call `mysqli_result::fetch_assoc` (just be sure that the $stmt object is open and result is stored). Now call the above function:-

```
//mysqliConnection is your mysqli connection object
if($stmt = $mysqli_connection->prepare($query))
{
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    while($assoc_array = fetchAssocStatement($stmt))
    {
        //do your magic
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK. i have tried:
**MYSQLi**

```
$sql = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? OR email = ?");
 $sql -> bind_param('ss',$uname, $email);
        $sql -> execute();
        $result = $sql -> get_result();
        $row=$result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

**PDO**

```
$sql = $conn -> prepare("SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username= :uname OR email = :email");
        $sql -> bindParam(':uname', $uname);
        $sql -> bindParam(':email', $email);
        $sql -> execute();

        $row=$sql -> fetchAll();
        print_r($row);
```

works fine for me. You get an 500 Error so check your prepare Statement. I think there is an  error which results in 500.

Comment: I've done everything you suggest still got the same error.

Comment: show me the code above please (without password etc)

Comment: it looks like your '$username' is not set in the 'insert' query

Comment: Please check this github gist for complete code: https://gist.github.com/Chandra0505/0705602f9a113d05d4f2e651b68c47d0

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I've already checked following points-
1. database is connected.
2. Form is receiving data from ajax.
3. working fine for selecting data from database using the code given on w3school website but I want to implement it using prepared statements.
4. working fine for inserting data into database using  prepared statements. but I'm not able to validate email and password using this.

Comment: change Line 45 $username to $uname; $username is not set at the moment and this will result in an error

Comment: Sorry not working same error.

Comment: i have updated your git. changed 43;46 $result <->$row

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Still it is not working but I resolved this issue from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result

Comment: Because of the MySQL Native Driver (mysqlnd) driver is not available, and therefore use bind_result and fetch instead of get_result .