# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in

Tags: php

I am new in PHP. I have got one API which have most of functions like below

```
function getUserByEmail($conn,$email)
    {
        $user = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE email = ?");
        $user->bind_param("s", $email);
        $user->execute();
        $result = $user->get_result();
        $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $user->close();
        return $data;
    }
```

Its working fine in one of my hosting with **namecheap** which have `nd_mysqli` **enabled**. But in my **hostgator** hosting, its giving error.

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in

I am unable to enable that extension in Hostgator so I want replace it with answers written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result) or other way.

But I am not getting idea how I can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[bind result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

So if the MySQL Native Driver (mysqlnd) driver is not available, and therefore using bind_result and fetch instead of get_result, the code becomes:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT col1,col2 FROM table_users WHERE email = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind variables to prepared statement */
    $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2);
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
 }
```