# PHP mysqli_fetch_assoc working on localhost but not on godaddy server

Tags: php

I have this code that works on my localhost but not on godaddy server

```
$sql = 'SELECT hash FROM user_for_activation where registeredDate = ?;';
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
    echo "SQL Connection Failed";
}
else{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$dateRegistered);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $hash = $row['hash'];
    }

}
```

I am getting an error on line `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` but this works on my localhost. Is this a compatibility issue?

Comment: Error text says what?

Comment: @u_mulder statusText says 'Internal Server Error'

Comment: You might not have mysqlnd. The function mysqli_stmt_get_result is available only with mysqlnd.

Comment: Then read error logs and clarify error. Noone can guess it.

Comment: it says `Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined method mysqli\_stmt::get\_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result)

Comment: @Dharman upon checking mysqlnd is enabled

Comment: How did you check that? Did you see it in the result of `phpinfo`?

Comment: @Dharman yes I checked inside the control panel. I tried disabling mysqli but still throw some errors