# PHP Database Table Display

Tags: php

I have an assignment in which needs to be corrected. My code has all working functionality. However, I need my code to be able to display my reservations table when the page is initially opened and loaded. Currently, the table is only shown when another flight is added. I believe I am missing a few lines of code or am not putting the code in the correct section. Please help.

```
> <html>
<head>
<title>HW09</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>HW09 - Airline Reservation</h1>

<form>


<h3>Find a flight:</h3>
<?php
  include("config.php");
  
  $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost",$username,$dbpassword,"CHA") or die ("Cannot open database");
  $sql="SELECT * FROM `AirportList` ";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

  print "<label>From: </label>";
  print "<select name='from'>";
  while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {

    print "<option value='" . $row['AirportCode'] . "'>" . $row['AirportName'] . "</option>\n";
  }
  print "</select>\n";

  print "<br>";

  $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

  print "<label>To:     </label>";
  print "<select name='to'>";
  while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {

    print "<option value='" . $row['AirportCode'] . "'>" . $row['AirportName'] . "</option>\n";
  }
  print "</select>\n";

  print "<br>";

  print   "<label>Date: </label>";
  print "<input type=\"date\" name=\"datee\" id=\"datee\" >";

  print"<br>
  <input type='submit' value='Find Flights'>
  </br>";

  $de = $_GET['datee'];
  $d = str_replace("-","",$de);
  $from = $_GET['from'];
  $to = $_GET['to'];

  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `Flights` WHERE `Date` LIKE '$d' AND `Takeoff` LIKE '$from' AND `Landing` LIKE '$to' ";
    print "<br />";
    if ($_GET) {
      print "<p>Let's find a reservation</p>";
      $result2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);

      $count = 0;
      while ($num = $result2 -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $count = $count + 1;
      }
      print "<p>We have " . $count . " options</p><br />";
      $result2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);
      if ($_GET['datee']) {
        print "
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Seats</th>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>To</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Flight#</th>
          </tr>";
      }
      
      while ($info = $result2 -> fetch_assoc()) {

        
          print"
          <form>
          <tr> 
            <td> 
              <input type='hidden' name='addflight' value=" . $info['Serial'] . "> 
              <input type='submit' name='Reserve' value='Reserve'> 
            </td> 
            <td> 
              <select name='seats'>";
                for ($x = 1; $x <= 11; $x++) {
                  print"<option value= " . $x . ">" . $x . "</option>";
                } 
              print"</td> 
         
            <td>" . $info['Takeoff'] . "</td><td>" . $info['Landing'] . "<td>" . $info['Time'] . "</td><td>" . $info['Flightnum'] . "</td></tr> 
          </form>";
      }
      print "</table>";
      if (isset($_GET['Reserve'])) {

        $connect3=mysqli_connect("localhost",$username,$dbpassword,"jasonlalaki_HW09") or die ("Cannot open database");
        $sql3="INSERT INTO `Reservations` (`ResSerial`, `Seats`) VALUES (" . $_GET['addflight'] . ", " . $_GET['seats'] . ");";
        $result3 = mysqli_query($connect3,$sql3);

        $sql4="SELECT * FROM `Reservations` ";
        $result4 = mysqli_query($connect3,$sql4);
        print"
        <table border=1>
        <tr>
          <th>Delete</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Flight</th>
          <th>From</th>
          <th>To</th>
          <th>Seats</th>
        </tr>";
        while ($row1 = $result4 -> fetch_assoc()) {
          $sql5="SELECT * FROM `Flights` WHERE `Serial` = " . $row1['ResSerial'];
          $result5 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql5);
          while ($info2 = $result5 -> fetch_assoc()) {
          
            print"
            <form>
            <tr> 
              <td> 
                <input type='submit' name='Delete' value='Delete'> 
              </td> 
              <td>" . $info2['Date'] . "</td><td>" . $info2['Time'] . "</td><td>" . $info2['Flightnum'] . "</td><td>" . $info2['Takeoff'] . "</td><td>" . $info2['Landing'] . "</td><td style=\"text-align: right;\">" . $row1['Seats'] . "</td></tr> 
            </form>";
          }  
        }
        print"
        </table>";
      }
    }

?>

</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I would start by taking the code that generates the table you want and putting that in a function. Then you can just call that when you need it.

Comment: You have multiple connections to the data base. If you don't need to connect as a different user to access a different database. You can specify the database in your sql. like SELECT * FROM dbname.tablename You will also want to look up prepared statements for sql. The sooner you start using them the better.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: @Jason K Would you know how to go about with the suggestion? I need like a very similar example to walkthrough this.

Answer (score 1):

After studying your code a bit, I decided to rewrite it - including the naming conventions of the tables, to show you a "best practice" example. The table structures chosen by me are certainly not the correct ones, but I didn't consider this here of big relevance.

**Suggestions:**

- You should always **avoid printing HTML code using PHP code**. For example, avoid snippets like this: `print "<label>From: </label>";`. Write HTML code as normal: `<label>From: </label>`.
- There are the cases where PHP code must be printed inside HTML controls (values, attributes, etc). Then try to **print only PHP variables**, no complex code. Instead of `<input value="<?php echo $selectedFlightDate ?? ''; ?>" ... />` optimize to `<?php $defaultFlightDate = $selectedFlightDate ?? ''; ?> <input value="<?php echo $defaultFlightDate; ?>" ... />`.
- Try to **separate the database querying PHP codes from the rest of the page**. The querying results should be fetched in arrays, which will easily be used later in the page.
- Don't hesitate to **use pronounceable and intention-revealing names** for variables, constants, functions, etc. So, instead of `<input type="date" name="datee">` use `<input type="date" name="flightDate">`. Or, in PHP, instead of `$de = $_GET['datee'];` use `$flightDate = $_GET['flightDate'];`.
- You are **using MySQLi extension**. I suggest you to **use the object oriented classes and methods** of it, instead of the procedural functions of it. For example, instead of `$connection = mysqli_connect(/* args list */);` (procedural style) you should use `$connection = new mysqli(/* args list */);` (object oriented style). See the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php).
- You are using MySQLi database extension, but I strongly advice you to **switch to the [PDO extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)** as soon as possible!
- In order to **avoid malicious SQL injections**, you should always **use the so-called [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)**. You'll notice that I never used `mysqli_query`, because it's not compatible with the process of statements preparing. I commented my code a lot, especially where I prepared the SQL statement for fetching the flights list (`SELECT * FROM flights WHERE ...`).

---

**Code:**

- Change my db credentials with yours.
- I appended the string "_test" to all table names for quickly creating them without affecting yours, and testing.

***connection.php:***

```
<?php

/*
 * This page contains the code for creating a mysqli connection instance.
 */

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'tests');
define('USERNAME', 'tests');
define('PASSWORD', 'tests');

// Error reporting.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); /* SET IT TO 0 ON A LIVE SERVER !!! */

/*
 * Enable internal report functions. This enables the exception handling.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
 */
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// Create a new db connection.
$connection = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);
```

***index.php:***

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

/*
 * ==================================================================
 * Define flags for the various operations. Can be very useful later.
 * ==================================================================
 */
$searchingFlightsStarted = false;
$flightReservationStarted = false;
$reservationDeletionStarted = false;

/*
 * =========================================================
 * Operations upon submission of form "searchingFlightsForm"
 * =========================================================
 */
if (isset($_POST['searchFlightsButton'])) {
    $searchingFlightsStarted = true;

    /*
     * Read submitted values.
     */
    $selectedStartingAirport = $_POST['startingAirport'] ?? '';
    $selectedDestinationAirport = $_POST['destinationAirport'] ?? '';
    // I didn't applied any formatting to the date value. Do it, if you need to. 
    $selectedFlightDate = $_POST['flightDate'] ?? '';

    /*
     * Validate submitted values.
     */
    if (empty($selectedStartingAirport)) {
        $errorMessages[] = 'Please select a starting point.';
    }

    if (empty($selectedDestinationAirport)) {
        $errorMessages[] = 'Please select a destination.';
    }

    if (empty($selectedFlightDate)) {
        $errorMessages[] = 'Please select a date for the flight.';
    }

    /*
     * If no validation errors yet, proceed with searching flights.
     * Note the use of the prepared statement in order to avoid malicious SQL injections.
     */
    if (!isset($errorMessages)) {
        /*
         * The SQL statement to be prepared. Notice the so-called markers,
         * e.g. the "?" signs. They will be replaced later with the
         * corresponding values when using mysqli_stmt::bind_param.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
         */
        $sql = 'SELECT * 
                FROM flights_test 
                WHERE 
                    date = ? AND 
                    takeoff LIKE ? AND 
                    landing LIKE ?';

        /**
         * Prepare the SQL statement for execution, but 
         * ONLY ONCE - read the docs to find out why.
         * 
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
         */
        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

        $boundSelectedStartingAirport = '%' . $selectedStartingAirport . '%';
        $boundSelectedDestinationAirport = '%' . $selectedDestinationAirport . '%';

        /*
         * Bind variables for the parameter markers ("?") in the
         * SQL statement that was passed to prepare(). The first
         * argument of bind_param() is a string that contains one
         * or more characters which specify the types of the
         * corresponding bind variables (string, integer, etc).
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
         */
        $statement->bind_param(
            'sss',
            $selectedFlightDate,
            $boundSelectedStartingAirport,
            $boundSelectedDestinationAirport
        );

        /*
         * Execute the prepared SQL statement.
         * When executed any parameter markers which exist, 
         * e.g. each "?" character, will automatically be 
         * replaced with the appropriate data.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
         */
        $statement->execute();

        /*
         * Get the result set from the prepared statement.
         *
         * NOTA BENE:
         * Available only with mysqlnd ("MySQL Native Driver")! If this
         * is not installed, uncomment "extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll" in
         * php.ini and restart web server and mysql service. Or use the following instead:
         * mysqli_stmt::store_result + mysqli_stmt::bind_result + mysqli_stmt::fetch.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php
         * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result
         */
        $result = $statement->get_result();

        // Fetch all found flights and save them in an array for later use.
        $foundFlights = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        /*
         * Free the memory associated with the result. You should
         * always free your result when it is not needed anymore.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php
         */
        $result->close();

        /*
         * Close the prepared statement. It also deallocates the statement handle.
         * If the statement has pending or unread results, it cancels them
         * so that the next query can be executed.
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php
         */
        $statement->close();
    }
}

/*
 * ==========================================================
 * Operations upon submission of form "flightReservationForm"
 * ==========================================================
 */
if (isset($_POST['reserveFlightButton'])) {
    $flightReservationStarted = true;

    /*
     * Read submitted values.
     */
    $flightIdToReserve = $_POST['flightIdToReserve'];
    $seatToReserve = $_POST['seatToReserve'];

    /*
     * Proceed with the reservation of the selected flight.
     * Note the use of the prepared statement.
     */
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO reservations_test (
                flight_id,
                seat
            ) VALUES (
                ?, ?
            )';

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bind_param('ii', $flightIdToReserve, $seatToReserve);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->close();

    $successMessages[] = 'The reservation of the selected flight was successfully performed.';
}

/*
 * ============================================================
 * Operations upon submission of form "reservationDeletionForm"
 * ============================================================
 */
if (isset($_POST['deleteReservationButton'])) {
    $reservationDeletionStarted = true;

    /*
     * Read submitted values.
     */
    $reservationIdToDelete = $_POST['reservationIdToDelete'];

    /*
     * Proceed with the deletion of the selected flight.
     * Note the use of the prepared statement.
     */
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM reservations_test
            WHERE id = ?';

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bind_param('i', $reservationIdToDelete);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->close();

    $successMessages[] = 'The selected flight reservation was successfully deleted.';
}

/*
 * ===========================================================
 * Fetch the airports list (used in the searching comboboxes).
 * Note the use of the prepared statement.
 * ===========================================================
 */
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM airports_test';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();

// Fetch all airports and save them in an array for later use.
$airports = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$result->close();
$statement->close();

/*
 * =======================================================
 * Fetch the reservations list, which is always displayed.
 * Note the use of the prepared statement.
 * =======================================================
 */
$sql = 'SELECT
            r.id,
            r.flight_id,
            f.date,
            f.time,
            f.flight_no,
            f.takeoff,
            f.landing,
            r.seat
        FROM reservations_test AS r
        LEFT JOIN flights_test AS f ON 
            r.flight_id = f.id';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();

// Fetch all reservations and save them in an array for later use.
$reservations = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$result->close();
$statement->close();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />

        <title>Demo</title>

        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <h1>
                Airline Reservation
            </h1>
        </header>

        <section class="messages">
            <?php
            /*
             *  Display all error messages.
             */
            if (isset($errorMessages)) {
                foreach ($errorMessages as $errorMessage) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="error">
                        <?php echo $errorMessage; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }

            /*
             *  Display all success messages.
             */
            if (isset($successMessages)) {
                foreach ($successMessages as $successMessage) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="success">
                        <?php echo $successMessage; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </section>

        <section>
            <header>
                <h3>
                    Search flights:
                </h3>
            </header>
            <article>
                <form id="searchingFlightsForm" method="post" action="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>From: </label>
                        <select name="startingAirport">
                            <option value="">-- Select a starting point --</option>
                            <?php
                            if ($airports) {// if any records available
                                foreach ($airports as $airport) {
                                    $airportCode = $airport['code'];
                                    $airportName = $airport['name'];

                                    $attributeSelected = ($airportCode === $selectedStartingAirport) ?
                                        'selected' :
                                        '';
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $airportCode; ?>" <?php echo $attributeSelected; ?>>
                                        <?php echo $airportName; ?>
                                    </option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>To: </label>
                        <select name="destinationAirport">
                            <option value="">-- Select a destination --</option>
                            <?php
                            if ($airports) {// if any records available
                                foreach ($airports as $airport) {
                                    $airportCode = $airport['code'];
                                    $airportName = $airport['name'];

                                    $attributeSelected = ($airportCode === $selectedDestinationAirport) ?
                                        'selected' :
                                        '';
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $airportCode; ?>" <?php echo $attributeSelected; ?>>
                                        <?php echo $airportName; ?>
                                    </option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Date: </label>
                        <?php $defaultFlightDate = $selectedFlightDate ?? ''; ?>
                        <input type="date" id="flightDate" name="flightDate" value="<?php echo $defaultFlightDate; ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>&nbsp;</label>
                        <button type="submit" name="searchFlightsButton" class="formButton" value="Search Flights">
                            Search Flights
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </article>
        </section>

        <?php
        $numberOfFoundFlights = isset($foundFlights) ? count($foundFlights) : 0;
        ?>
        <section>
            <header>
                <h3>
                    <?php
                    $foundFlightsMessage = $numberOfFoundFlights > 0 ?
                        'Found flights: ' . $numberOfFoundFlights . '. Let\'s make a reservation.' :
                        'No flights found yet.';

                    echo $foundFlightsMessage;
                    ?>
                </h3>
            </header>
            <?php
            if ($numberOfFoundFlights > 0) {
                ?>
                <article>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Select</th>
                                <th>Seat</th>
                                <th>From</th>
                                <th>To</th>
                                <th>Time</th>
                                <th>Flight #</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($foundFlights as $foundFlight) {
                                $flightId = $foundFlight['id'];
                                $flightTakeoff = $foundFlight['takeoff'];
                                $flightLanding = $foundFlight['landing'];
                                $flightTime = $foundFlight['time'];
                                $flightNumber = $foundFlight['flight_no'];
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php
                                        /*
                                         * You are not allowed to enclose a table row in a "form" tag!
                                         * Though, in HTML5, you can define a form for each table row 
                                         * wherever you want on the page, and then add the attribute "form" 
                                         * to each control residing outside of it, but destined to belong 
                                         * to it. The "form" attribute MUST contain the id of the form 
                                         * to which the current control should belong. As example see
                                         * the comboboxes named "seatToReserve" bellow.
                                         */
                                        ?>
                                        <form id="flightReservationForm_<?php echo $flightId; ?>" class="flightReservationForm" method="post" action="">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="flightIdToReserve" value="<?php echo $flightId; ?>">
                                            <button type="submit" name="reserveFlightButton" class="columnButton" value="Reserve">
                                                Reserve
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="seatToReserve" form="flightReservationForm_<?php echo $flightId; ?>">
                                            <?php
                                            for ($seat = 1; $seat <= 11; $seat++) {
                                                ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $seat; ?>">
                                                    <?php echo $seat; ?>
                                                </option>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><?php echo $flightTakeoff; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $flightLanding; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $flightTime; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $flightNumber; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </article>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </section>

        <?php
        $numberOfReservations = $reservations ? count($reservations) : 0;
        ?>
        <section>
            <header>
                <h3>
                    <?php
                    $reservationsMessage = $numberOfReservations > 0 ?
                        'Reservations:' :
                        'No reservations available yet.';

                    echo $reservationsMessage;
                    ?>
                </h3>
            </header>
            <?php
            if ($numberOfReservations > 0) {
                ?>
                <article>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Time</th>
                                <th>Flight</th>
                                <th>From</th>
                                <th>To</th>
                                <th>Seat</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($reservations as $reservation) {
                                $reservationId = $reservation['id'];
                                $reservationFlightId = $reservation['flight_id'];
                                $reservationDate = $reservation['date'];
                                $reservationTime = $reservation['time'];
                                $reservationFlightNumber = $reservation['flight_no'];
                                $reservationTakeoff = $reservation['takeoff'];
                                $reservationLanding = $reservation['landing'];
                                $reservationSeat = $reservation['seat'];
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <form id="reservationDeletionForm_<?php echo $reservationId; ?>" class="reservationDeletionForm" method="post" action="">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="reservationIdToDelete" value="<?php echo $reservationId; ?>">
                                            <button type="submit" name="deleteReservationButton" class="columnButton" value="Delete">
                                                Delete
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><?php echo $reservationDate; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $reservationTime; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $reservationFlightNumber; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $reservationTakeoff; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $reservationLanding; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $reservationSeat; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </article>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

***styles.css:***

```
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }
:root { font-size: 16px; }
body { margin: 0; padding: 20px; font-family: "Verdana", Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1rem; font-weight: 400; background-color: #fff; }

table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table, th, td { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
th, td { padding: 7px; text-align: left; }
th { background-color: #f4f4f4; }
tbody tr:hover { background: yellow; }

.messages { width: 50%; }
.messages .error { background-color: #e83e8c; color: #fff; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; }
.messages .success { background-color: #5cb85c; color: #fff; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; }

#searchingFlightsForm { width: 50%; padding: 20px; background-color: #f4f4f4; }
#searchingFlightsForm .form-group { padding: 5px; }
#searchingFlightsForm label { display: inline-block; min-width: 70px; }
#searchingFlightsForm select { min-width: 240px; }
#searchingFlightsForm input[type="date"] { min-width: 240px; padding: 7px; }

.formButton { padding: 5px 7px; background-color: #009926; color: #fff; }
.columnButton { padding: 3px 5px; background-color: #0086b3; color: #fff; }

form.flightReservationForm { margin: 0; }

form.reservationDeletionForm { margin: 0; }
```

---

**The used table definitions and testing data:**

***"airports_test" table:***

```
CREATE TABLE `airports_test` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

id|code|name                |
--|----|--------------------|
 1|LON |London Airport      |
 2|BUA |Buenos Aires Flights|
 3|BUD |Budapest Airport    |
```

***"flights_test" table:***

```
CREATE TABLE `flights_test` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `takeoff` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `landing` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flight_no` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

id|date      |time    |takeoff|landing|flight_no|
--|----------|--------|-------|-------|---------|
 1|2020-12-27|15:38:00|BUA    |BUD    |43245    |
 2|2020-12-29|22:44:00|BUD    |LON    |245      |
 3|2020-12-30|05:31:00|BUD    |BUA    |876643   |
 4|2020-12-30|10:00:00|LON    |BUD    |5443     |
 5|2020-12-30|18:45:00|LON    |BUD    |4287     |
```

***"reservations_test" table:***

```
CREATE TABLE `reservations_test` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `flight_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `seat` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

id|flight_id|seat|
--|---------|----|
```

---

**Resources:**

- [(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)
- [How to use mysqli properly](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli)
- [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting)
- [Clean, high quality code: a guide on how to become a better programmer](https://www.butterfly.com.au/blog/website-development/clean-high-quality-code-a-guide-on-how-to-become-a-better-programmer)

Answer (score 0):

I took one of your sql statements and made it a prepaired statement.

You need preparied statements id Mike O'Leary need to fly to O'Heir airport.

```
<?php

$msi = new mysqli('localhost','misc01','!howTO001','test');

$stmt = $msi->prepare('
  Select
    * 
  From
    Flights
  Where 
    Date LIKE ? And
    Takeoff LIKE ? And
    Landing LIKE ? 
';
  $stmt->bind_param('sss', $d, $from, $to);
  $stmt->execute();

  $rslt = $stmt->get_result();
  echo('<pre>');
  print_r($rslt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```