# php db class with mysqli, which support multiple connections

Tags: php, class, connection, mysqli

The thing is that I need to write a db class with mysqli and it should support multiple connections to different databases.
I know that multiple connections is bad, but I don't have any other choice.

If there is any good example of class which supports multiple connections?

Do you know any tips that I should take into consideration when I will start writing the class? What is the best practice in my case?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You could have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384191/how-to-make-a-proper-mysqli-extension-class-with-prepared-statements and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage to get a first idea.

Comment: Why 'multiple connections is bad'? What other way to connect to two ro more servers or use asynchronous queries?

Comment: @Quasdunk thanks, I already looked over this topic and other which I found on the StackOverflow.

Comment: @Mchi, because I read it and heard couple of times it is better to have all your tables in one database, rather than having them in different databases

Comment: @user616822: This is not true. Sure, as far as a single application is concerned, usually having just one database is best. However sometimes you just need to work with several databases sitting on different servers (often running different database systems). `Multiple connections is bad` can also mean something different. In PHP application, you usually should create just one connection per database used i.e. don't create a new connection before each query - reuse existing connection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind, is a container class, that stores MySQLi object in it.
Something like this:

```
class MySQLiContainer extends SplObjectStorage{
  public function newConnection($host = null, $username = null, $passwd = null, $dbname = null, $port = null, $socket = null) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $passwd, $dbname, $port, $socket);
    $this->attach($mysqli);
    return $mysqli;
  }
}

//usage

$mysqliContainer = new MySQLiContainer();

$c1 = $mysqliContainer->newConnection('localhost','root','root','localDatabase');
$c1->query('SELECT ....');

$c2 = $mysqliContainer->newConnection('mysql.remotehost.net','hackermom','bobbytables','schoolDatabase');

$name = 'Robert\'); DROP TABLE students;--';

$c2->multi_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE name = '$name'");
```

Without knowing more about functionality required, it's hard to say if this is a good idea though ;)

More info about [SplObjectStorage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) class.

Comment: @Mchi, Thank you very much, I looked over your code. It is pretty clear. Not sure exactly what functionality is needed. I'm currently reading about mysqli. If I will have any questions related to this I will write it here.

Comment: You should probably ask a new question with more detail. If not, remember you can edit your question. Don't add any new information in comments ;)